# Why I get the "Set::write: "Tag Times in is Protected." error?

Tags: vector-calculus

Why I get the error below with this code:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

ρ = 1000;
g = 9.80665;
μ = 0.001;
p[x_, y_, z_, t_] = {x^2, Sqrt[y], -z, t^3};
f[x_, y_, z_, t_] = {-x^2, Sqrt[y]/2, z, t^2};

ρ Dt[v, t] = -Gradient[p] + μ Laplacian[v] + f
```

---

### Error:

```
Set::write: "Tag Times in 1000\ Dt[v,t] is Protected."
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve the Navier Stokes's equation? IF so, you should look at `NDSolve`... If you are just trying to get rid of the error, switching `=` with `==` in the final line helps... check `ref/character/Equal` in Mathematica Help.

Comment: See also: [How do I identify the source of a “Tag times protected” error?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any time you try to execute a command of the form `a*b=c`, you'll generate this error:

[image]

Of course, that's exactly what you've done in your last line:

```
ρ Dt[v, t] = -Gradient[p] + μ Laplacian[v] + f
```

We can see the issue more clearly if we examine the left side of the equation in `FullForm`

```
FullForm[a*b]
(* Out: Times[a,b] *)
```

Furthermore, `Times` is protected.

```
Attributes[Times]
(* Out: {Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected} *)
```

Thus, you're trying to set the value of a protected symbol.  As rm-rf points out, it's not just about removing the `ρ`, as otherwise you're trying to set the value of `Dt`.

Perhaps more to the point - if you want to represent an equation that you want to solve, you should type:

```
ρ Dt[v, t] == -Gradient[p] + μ Laplacian[v] + f
```

Note the double equals sign.  This *tests* for equality, rather than *setting* a value - which is what you generally want when solving an equation.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the _why_? OP clearly has no clue why it happened, and if he merely takes this suggestion and removes the `ρ` to not make it of the form `a*b=c`, then he'll get a `Tag Dt is Protected` error... back to square 1 :)