# How do I identify the source of a "Tag times protected" error?

Tags: warning-messages, syntax, debugging, faq

I have some code that looks like

```
Table[
    a = 1;
    b = {2, 3}
    c = i;,
    {i, 2}
]
```

which gives an error:

> Set::write: Tag Times in c {2,3} is Protected. >>

In this case, it is quite clear that there is a semicolon missing after `b = {2, 3}`, which is causing this error. However, sometimes I encounter this in large code blocks spanning several lines, which is very difficult to debug.

How can I automate this semicolon hunting to make debugging easier?

Comment: Worth to mention that `Tag Times ... is Protected` message is in 90% cases the result of a missing semicolon.

Comment: Please, upvote the comment of Kuba!

Comment: @Rexcirus  I laughed out loud at that (A+)

Comment: Or a comma! That is what I usually find missing.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a function `findBadSets` that will find any explicitly bad `Set`/`SetDelayed` attempts in a given expression.  Simply wrap it around a syntactically complete block of code, or follow the block with `// findBadSets` and the errors are printed one per row, protected symbol followed by complete left-hand side for each bad Set:

```
(* your example *) // findBadSets
```

[image]

Code for the function:

```
SetAttributes[findBadSets, HoldFirst]

findBadSets[expr_] :=
  Cases[
    Unevaluated @ expr,
    (Set | SetDelayed)[bad : head_Symbol[___], _]
      /; MemberQ[Attributes@head, Protected] :>
        HoldForm[Row[{head, bad}, Spacer[50]]],
   -1] // Column
```

See also:

- [Why I get the "Set::write: "Tag Times in is Protected." error?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11868/121)

Comment: WoW, so useful!

Comment: @matheorem My pleasure. :-)

Comment: That's certainly a faq.

Comment: @Kuba thanks for tagging.

Comment: This is a perfect example of what we could get from code helping functions. For some time now that WRI talks about the eventual inclusion of code improvement suggestion tools. A typical example given is the suggestion of WL functions that could do exactly what the user is programming with a more complex code. But even simpler things can be included, like the small code of Mr. Wizard, but also, for instance, a warning check of "all" the things listed on our common pitfalls post. Is there a frontend framework missing for this purpose? I would even be willing to participate/$ on a crowdfunding...

Comment: lot area = lotlength*lotwidth // findBadSets not working in Vers. 12.3, at least for me.

Comment: @StuartPoss Try `lot area = lotlength*lotwidth; // findBadSets` or `findBadSets[lot area = lotlength*lotwidth]` -- it has to do with the precedence of `//` relative to `=`.

Answer (score 14):

One can use `Trace` for this.  I stuck in an extra, different error to show it is omitted in the output.  It should also be clear how to trace other error messages.

```
foo = Trace[
  Table[
    a = 1/0;
    b = {2, 3} 
    c = i;,
   {i, 2}],
  HoldPattern@Message[Set::write, ___],
  TraceAbove -> True]
(* Power::infty, Set::write errors *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you would like a function like [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) to apply to a code block, we can wrap it up like this:

```
traceSet = Function[code,
  Trace[
   code,
   HoldPattern@Message[Set::write, __],
   TraceAbove -> True],
  HoldAll]
```

Here is a way to view the list of lists of lists of output, somewhat reminiscent of WReach's [traceView](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29340#29340).  (His function is built on `TraceScan`, which I could not get to work in the way above.  The option `TraceAbove -> True` seems to be ignored.  Is that a bug?)

```
Clear[ov];
ov[{e1_HoldForm, rest___}, open_: False] := 
  OpenerView[{e1, Column[ov[#, open] & /@ {rest}, Dividers -> All]}, open];
ov[e_, _] := e
```

Example:

```
ov[foo, True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can see the offending code comes from

```
a = 1/0; b = {2, 3} c = i;
```

which leads to the actual error, `{2, 3} c = i`.  Note that the error message already informs us that the immediate source is `c {2,3}`.

If it's a very large chunk of code, you can select the bottom segment of the evaluation chain as follows.  The length of the chain is controlled by

```
Length@First@pos == 5
```

which can be adjusted to suit:

```
Cases[foo, 
  e_List /; 
   With[{pos = Position[e, HoldPattern@Message[Set::write, ___]]},
    Length[pos] == 1 && Length@First@pos == 5], Infinity] // 
 Column[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could also apply the `OpenerView` to each element in the output by adding to the pattern in the second argument of `Cases` the code `:> ov[e, True]` to make it a transformation rule.

Answer (score 8):

After reading [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119307/1871) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78103/1871), I noticed that the debugger is also useful for identifying the error source in this case. You just need to:

1. Go to **Evaluation** and check on **Debugger**.
2. Check on **Break at Messages** and click the **Show Stack** button (alternatively you can click the button after running the erroneous code) in the newly opened panel.
3. Run the erroneous code.
4. Go to the bottom of **Stack** window (opened by the **Show Stack** button), click the last button, and the erroneous part of code will be highlighted:

[image]

5. Click on **Abort** in the panel (in some cases you may need to click for several times) to stop the evaluation, and correct the discovered error.

Answer (score 6):

A couple other ideas. One is to print the stack when a message occurs:

```
TracePrint[
    Table[
        a = 1;
        b = {2, 3}
        c = i;,
        {i, 2}
    ],
    _Message,
    TraceAction->(Print[Stack[_][[-3]]]&)
]
```

> {2,3} c=1
>
> Set::write: Tag Times in c {2,3} is Protected.
>
> {2,3} c=2
>
> Set::write: Tag Times in c {2,3} is Protected.
>
> {Null, Null}

Another is to just click on the ... to the left of the message, and then click on "Show Stack Trace". You will see the problematic `Set` expression in the stack trace.

Comment: A "meta" question here:  How does a problem like this get 14,000 views when adjacent questions get roughly 30 views?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it is 5y old, probably was on Hot across SE, it is high in results for `Set::write: Tag Times is Protected` query. And we link other questions here.

Comment: A great answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes** it can **also** be caused by **wrongly constructing functions with subscripts**, and the "`findBadSets`" solution above may not return anything useful at all. And also Clear[ ] wont help and one may need to restart the kernel.

*P.D. Restarting the kernel usually solves 10% of my bad code problems.*

I.e.: Lets imagine we wanted to construct a function $f_n(x)=x+1$. Our first attempt:

[image]

So, restarting the kernel (**Evaluation **menu** -> Quit Kernel -> Local**) and trying the proper way:

[image]

Comment: The trouble with `Subscript[]` is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395) (basic advice: don't use it this way; a better practice would be `f /: Subscript[f, n] = x + 1`). The problem with `findBadSets` seems to be with bad sets of subvalues and not with `Subscript[]` per se. `findBadSets` seems to work with bad sets of downvalues and ownvalues.  Carl's `TracePrint[]` method handles all of them, as well as answers the question of *how to find* the source of the error(s).