# How does Mathematica interpret a expression?

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, kernel

I'm a beginner to Mathematica.
I'd read several document. But I still have a problem.
For example, every expression in Mathematica
are of the form  `Head[expr1,expr2,...]`
If I type `Plus[3^3,6*9]`, what is the practical order Mathematica interpret?

1. Interpret `Plus` first, and then interpret expr1, expr2,...
   In other words, from 'outside' to 'inside'
2. Evaluate `Power[3,3]` first, then `Times[6,9]`, after evaluating these,
   then interpret `Plus`

Or there may be other ways Mathematica use? What else should I notice?
Thanks for your replying and forgiving my bad English grammar. :-)

Comment: Order of evaluation can get complicated but in general it is inside out. Here #2 is correct. Take a look at `Plus[3^3, 6*9] // Trace`

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html

Comment: Take a look at this  Q&A: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29339/131.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html

Comment: (I'm Eric)
Is there a exception? For example, If I type Hold[{a+b,3*6}], Mathematica should still calculate a+b,3*6 first?

Comment: The point of `Hold` is that what is inside it *does not* get evaluated :) But once you release the hold it would be evaluated in the standard order as you describe.

Comment: According to the tutorial Szablocs gave, the tutorial said "In the standard evaluation procedure, Mathematica first evaluates the head of an expression, and then evaluates each element of the expressions." I'm confusing. I feel this just said #1.

Comment: It evaluates the head by itself to decide what to do with the whole expression. Try this: `p = Plus;
p[3^3, 6*9] // Trace`. Notice how it evalutes `p`, then it evalutes what's inside, then it evaluates the whole expression including the head and the interior elements. That's how, for example, it knows not to evaluate the things inside `Hold`.

Comment: Now that I reread #1 I see I may have understood it differently than you meant. It "interprets" the head first, yes, but then it evaluates the interior expressions before evaluating the head (as applied to the interior expressions).

Comment: Thanks! Your example and explanation is very clear. I think I truly understand how it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a new question about interpreting. 
If I type Plus[3, b] // traceViewCompact, it displays that Mathematica used three steps.
But I type Plus[3, 4] // traceViewCompact, then it displays 4 steps(the expression of '7' appear twice). 
This is weird. I can't imagine why Mathematica do these similar works in different way.
http://ppt.cc/pmq~
You can see when evaluated Plus[3, 4], Mathematica seemed to evalute by the order: 3, then 4, then get 7, then get the result 7.

Comment: I strongly suggest you download David Wagner's book from [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/3066) and read Chapter 7.

Comment: OK, I will! Thanks.

Comment: I have checked the book, but I still have trouble understanding this. ps: I found the explanation in p.27(sec2.2) to be a similar but not the same thing I asked. So I ask for further explanation for this again, thanks!

My question is why: Plus[2,3] //traceViewCompact
Plus[2,b] //traceViewCompact
turned out to be different steps evaluating?
Namely 2->3->5->5(weird trivial evaluation) and 2,b,2+b

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this type of visualization will help understand the evaluation order better.  Things are printed in `InputForm` here, but please "think" `FullForm` when you look at expressions.

```
In[2]:= On[]
Plus[3^3,6*9]
Off[]
During evaluation of In[2]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>
During evaluation of In[2]:= Power::trace: 3^3 --> 27. >>
During evaluation of In[2]:= Times::trace: 6 9 --> 54. >>
During evaluation of In[2]:= Plus::trace: 3^3+6 9 --> 27+54. >>
During evaluation of In[2]:= Plus::trace: 27+54 --> 81. >>
Out[3]= 81

In[5]:= p=Plus
Out[5]= Plus

In[6]:= On[]
p[3^3,6 9]
Off[]
During evaluation of In[6]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>
During evaluation of In[6]:= p::trace: p --> Plus. >>
During evaluation of In[6]:= Power::trace: 3^3 --> 27. >>
During evaluation of In[6]:= Times::trace: 6 9 --> 54. >>
During evaluation of In[6]:= Plus::trace: p[3^3,6 9] --> 27+54. >>
During evaluation of In[6]:= Plus::trace: 27+54 --> 81. >>
Out[7]= 81
```

This shows the evaluation order clearly and *precisely*.  In the second example,

1. evaluate `p -> Plus`
2. `3^3 -> 27`
3. `6*9 -> 54`
4. `p[3^3,6 9] -> Plus[27, 54]`
5. `27+54 -> 81`

`TracePrint` shows the same information, but perhaps it's not quite as clear:

```
In[9]:= TracePrint[p[3^3,6 9]]
During evaluation of In[9]:=  p[3^3,6 9]
During evaluation of In[9]:=   p
During evaluation of In[9]:=   Plus
During evaluation of In[9]:=   (3^3)
During evaluation of In[9]:=    Power
During evaluation of In[9]:=    3
During evaluation of In[9]:=    3
During evaluation of In[9]:=   27
During evaluation of In[9]:=   6 9
During evaluation of In[9]:=    Times
During evaluation of In[9]:=    6
During evaluation of In[9]:=    9
During evaluation of In[9]:=   54
During evaluation of In[9]:=  27+54
During evaluation of In[9]:=  81
Out[9]= 81
```

It also mentions subexpressions that evaluate to themselves (i.e. don't evaluate), e.g. `Times -> Times` or `6 -> 6`.

The evaluation sequence is documented in detail here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html

Comment: Thanks! But in your last paragraph, I still can't see why does `TracePrint[a + b]` prints a->b->a+b then not again a+b?(not like `TracePrint[3+2]`). Is it because there's no probability that can make a+b turn into another expression? I think I have been familiar with the evaluation order now. But that point confuse me~

Comment: `TracePrint[a + b]` prints `Plus[a,b]` first because that's where it starts.  Then, it takes each element of this expression one by one.  Note that the next three lines it prints are indented by a space, meaning that these are part of the expression printed before them.  Now it prints `Plus`, meaning `Plus` evaluates to itself `a`, meaning `a` evaluates to itself, `b`, meaning `b` evaluates to itself.  Done.  Any expression that doesn't change anymore is printed only once.  Thus `Plus`, `a`, `b` and `Plus[a,b]` are all printed only once.

Comment: Is it different from `3+2`? `TracePrint[3 + 2]` prints Plus[3,2] first. Then it prints `Plus`, meaning `Plus` evaluates to itself, `3` meaning `3` evaluates to itself, `2`, meaning `2` evaluates to itself. Then done.

Comment: @Eric yes, it's different.  After the evaluator made sure that it's done with all subparts of `3+2` (i.e. Plus, 3, 2), it's still not yet done with `3+2` itself: it is at this point that it carries out the addition.  There's an extra line saying 5 at the end.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly realize it. The reason why `Plus[a,b]` and `Plus[3,2]` take different steps is: `Plus[a,b]` evaluate `Plus` first, then `a` and `b`, however, at the very time, by the rule defined for Plus, it doesn't have a rule corresponding to a `symbol` plus a `symbol`, so it keeps its form being `Plus[a,b]`.

Comment: On the other hand, it is not the same of `Plus[3,2]`. Mathematica kernel had already defined the rule for a `number` plus `number`, hence `Plus[2,3]` changes into `5`, and Mathematica again treat `5` as a new expression(but it suddenly find it to be an atomic expression), so evaluate `5` to `5` again. End. So the critical point is Mathematica can't tell what should `Plus[symbol,symbol]` be.