# Debuging in Mathematica

Tags: debugging

### Description

I have using ***Mathematica*** to solve all kinds of problems that encountered in my study. However, the function that I define to solve specific problem is not always right, in other words, it will occur all kinds of unexpected error. So I think I can debug it by looking over `middle values` of function's running process.

### Example

I write a function`GridLineData`to solve my data.`(the ultimate right edition as below, but I takes much time to debug it many times)`

```
GridLineData[data_List, Δ_] := Block[
 {sortData, length, OriginData, deleteData},
 sortData = DeleteDuplicates@(Sort@data);
 length = Length@sortData;
 OriginData =
  Append[
   Prepend[sortData, 2 sortData[[1]] - sortData[[2]]],
   2 sortData[[length]] - sortData[[length - 1]]];
 deleteData =
   List /@ (First /@ Select[
    Thread[List[Range[length - 1], Differences@sortData]],
    #[[2]] < Δ &]) + 1;
 Delete[Total@#/2 & /@ Partition[OriginData, 2, 1], deleteData]
]
```

**Using this fuction**

```
DebugData =
{{0.349661, 0.380297}, {0.858156, 0.8442}, {0.906745, 0.171579},
 {0.0847783, 0.277227}, {0.198453, 0.40206}, {0.941614, 0.347187}};
GridLineData[DebugData[[All, 1]], .1]
(*==>{0.027941, 0.141616, 0.274057, 0.603909, 0.959049}*)
```

### Question

When I debug this function, I always want to know its `middle value` in running process. I use a tedious method that `output the middle values as the return result of this function`. So the function can be rewritten as below:

```
  GridLineData[data_List, Δ_] := Block[
 {sortData, length, OriginData, deleteData},
 sortData = DeleteDuplicates@(Sort@data);
 length = Length@sortData;
 OriginData =
  Append[
   Prepend[sortData, 2 sortData[[1]] - sortData[[2]]],
   2 sortData[[length]] - sortData[[length - 1]]];
 deleteData =
   List /@ (First /@ Select[
    Thread[List[Range[length - 1], Differences@sortData]],
    #[[2]] < Δ &]) + 1;
  {sortData,OriginData,deleteData,
   Delete[Total@#/2 & /@ Partition[OriginData, 2, 1], deleteData]}
]
```

**Rerun the function that give middle values**

```
GridLineData[DebugData[[All, 1]], .1]
(**==>{{0.0847783, 0.198453, 0.349661, 0.858156, 0.906745, 
       0.941614}, {-0.0288964, 0.0847783, 0.198453, 0.349661, 0.858156, 
       0.906745, 0.941614, 0.976483}, {{5}, {6}}, {0.027941, 0.141616, 
       0.274057, 0.603909, 0.959049}})
```

I know the ***Mathematica*** has the inner function `Trace`, but it gives complex transform process. So my question is **How to extract middle value to debug in Mathematica enviroment.**

Comment: Have you tried the varieties of Monitor, such as Monitor, StepMonitor, and EvaluationMonitor? Maybe those will help you.

Comment: @seismatica,No,I've never heard of `Monitor, StepMonitor, and EvaluationMonitor`

Comment: Time to try em out ;)

Comment: @seismatica,+1,OK,I will have a try!Thanks

Comment: Also see Reap and Sow

Comment: I also quite like the debugger for this. You can set a breakpoint somewhere, and if a breakpoint is reached while we are inside a `Block`, you can still ask what values the local variables of `Block` have.

Comment: Regarding `Trace` and how hard it is to read it, look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29339/16) question and answers.