# How does one unpack the contents of a list while using rules to substitute values for each variable?

Tags: replacement, rule

My intention is having a large collection of variables (**symbols** to be more specific) in a list and substituting all the variables at once with a value using rule instead of going through each one, one at a time. I will explain in more detail bellow if that wasn't clear:

I was trying to substitute the values of a vector/list in mathematica with rules but it didn't work as expected.

So consider a function that takes a list:

```
fsquared[x_List] := x^2
```

then consider pre defining (*hard coding* the list you want to use):

```
xxx = {xxx1, xxx2}
```

then consider substituting ALL the values of the list, but instead of doing it one by one, substituting all at once:

```
fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}
```

the intended behaviour/output should be

```
{9,16}
```

but mathematica outputs:

```
{xxx1^2, xxx2^2}
```

Why is that? I wanted it to substitute each value inside the list with 3 and 4 i.e. the intended behavior is:

```
fsquared[xxx] /. {xxx1 -> 3, xxx2 -> 4}
```

the above definitively works, however, when the list of variables I want to substitute gets really long, the above method becomes a little ridiculous.

As in:

```
fsquared[xxx] /. {xxx1 -> 1, xxx2 -> 2, xxx3 -> 3, xxx4 -> 4, xxx5 -> 5, xxx6 -> 6, xxx7 -> 7}
```

I will also provide a screen shot to easy readability:

[image]

I've tried googling various things like unpacking lists, but so far, I've had no luck searching this. I am assuming something like this must exist, otherwise, it seems rather annoying to have a list of symbols and later decide to change their value and the only want to do it 1 by 1? yikes, that sucks.

I am aware that pattern matching and rule substitution is based on syntactic matching rather than semantic comparison on expressions. But still, is there no way to get this functionality that I am requesting using some built in function?

---

One caveat that I didn't mention is that I might have nested lists. So something like:

```
t1 = {a,b}

a = {a1, a2, a3}

b = {b1, b2, b3}
```

and I'd want:

```
t1 -> {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

or even something a tiny by more complicated like:

```
t2 = {c,d}

c = {c1, c2, c3}

d = {d1, d2, d3}
```

then define:

```
tBig = {t1,t2}
```

and it would be awesome if the following worked:

```
tBig -> {{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}}
```

if it would substitute each variable/symbol, one by one.

Comment: Try `fsquared[xxx] /. Thread[xxx -> {3, 4}]`. When you use `fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}` *Mathematica* tries to replace literal `{xxx1, xxx2}`, but such thing is not present in your `fsquared[xxx]` expression.

Comment: You haven't assigned values to `xxx1`, or `xxx2`. If I understand you correctly, what you want is `xxx:={xxx1,xxx2}`. Then you can do `fsquared/@xxx`, or add the `Listable` attribute to fsquared. Because of `:=` anytime you update `xxx1`, or `xxx2` re-evaluating `fsquared/@xxx` will return the result with the newly defined `xxx1`, or `xxx2`.

Comment: @jkuczm yep that seemed to work. After looking up what Thread does that makes sense `Thread[xxx -> {3, 4}] = {xxx1 -> 3, xxx2 -> 4}`. For your second comment, thanks for clarifying! As I noted in my question, I suspected that mathematica was only doing syntactic replacement, rather than semantic replacement and substituting as I intended it to do.

Comment: @jkuczm there is one small caveat that I didn't tell you about. I might have nested lists. So something like: `{{x1, x2},{x3, x4}} -> {{1,2},{3,4}}` should also be covered. Let me see what your suggestions does in that (recursive) case...

Comment: You can [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) your lists before passing them to `Rule`: `Thread[Flatten@tBig -> 
  Flatten@{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}]`. You may need to specify a level in second argument of `Flatten` if you replace symbol with a `List`. Or to make sure that given nested lists have compatible shapes [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) `Rule` over them at appropriate level and then flatten: `Flatten@MapThread[
  Rule, {tBig, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}}, 
  3]`

Comment: @jkuczm nice! I think that works...can't see if it breaks in any subtle way but it shouldn't, as long as the indices in the tensors match, as in `T1[i1][i2]...[in]` matches the `T2[i1][i2]...[in]`

the way I wrote it was: `Thread[h[Flatten[tBig], 
  Flatten[{{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, 
      d3}}}]]]` for this particular example. Where h is rule of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simple case in which you have variable names in flat list and their values in another, you can [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) `Rule` over those lists:

```
Thread[{a, b, c} -> {13, 4, 7}]
(* {a -> 13, b -> 4, c -> 7} *)
```

This gives flat list of rules that can be used in `Replace...` functions.

It also works for delayed rules:

```
Thread[{a, b} :> {2+2, 10 - 5}]
(* {a :> 2 + 2, b :> 10 - 5} *)
```

---

If you have your variables and values in nested lists you can define your own variants of `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` that will thread over all levels and return flattened result.

```
ClearAll[flatRule]
flatRule[lhs_List, rhs_] := Flatten@MapThread[flatRule, {lhs, rhs}]
flatRule[lhs_, rhs_] := lhs -> rhs

{a, {b, c}, {{d}}}~flatRule~{3, {7, 9}, {{5}}}
(* {a -> 3, b -> 7, c -> 9, d -> 5} *)
```

You can assign a list to a symbol:

```
{a, b}~flatRule~{3, {7, 9}}
(* {a -> 3, b -> {7, 9}} *)
```

If you accidentally use wrong shapes of lists, a warning will be printed:

```
{a, {b, c}}~flatRule~{2, 5}
(* MapThread::mptd: Object 5 at position {2, 2} in MapThread[flatRule,{{b,c},5}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions. >> *)
(* {a -> 2, MapThread[flatRule, {{b, c}, 5}]} *)
```

Usage in replacement:

```
a + b + c d /. {a, {b, c}, {{d}}}~flatRule~{x1, {x2, x3}, {{x4}}}
(* x1 + x2 + x3 x4 *)
```

Similar function for delayed rules:

```
ClearAll[flatRuleDelayed]
SetAttributes[flatRuleDelayed, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}]
flatRuleDelayed[lhs_List, rhs_] := Flatten@MapThread[flatRuleDelayed, Unevaluated@{lhs, rhs}]
flatRuleDelayed[lhs_, rhs_] := lhs :> rhs

{a, {b, c}, {{d}}}~flatRuleDelayed~{3, {2 + 5, 9}, {{Sequence[11, 4]}}}
(* {a :> 3, b :> 2 + 5, c :> 9, d :> Sequence[11, 4]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The general principal I will illustrate is that code should express intention.

**(1)** I'm going to suggest another approach. Each approach has its advantages, and due to the complicated way expressions can be evaluated (pattern restrictions, held arguments), each approach probably has drawbacks in certain situations.

The following is straightforward:

```
fsquared[xxx /. xxx -> {3, 4}]
```

This gets the order of evaluation right.  Of course on such a simple example, it seems a circuitous route to `fsquared[{3, 4}]`.  But with functions with complicated evaluation rules, such as `fsquared`, it is not clear what the line of code in itself means:

```
fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}
```

It depends on what `xxx` is at that the time of execution.

**(2)** A more important problem is the meaning of the code

```
xxx -> {3, 4}
```

If the intended meaning is "replace whatever matches the value of `xxx` (as a pattern) with the list `{3, 4}`", then there is no reason to complain about the result of

```
fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}
```

when `xxx = {xxx1, xxx2}`, because `fsquared[xxx]` evaluates to an expression that contains no instances of `{xxx1, xxx2}`.  But if the intention was to effect the replacements

```
{xxx1 -> 3, xxx2 -> 4}
```

then it is a weak representation of the intention.  One of the weakness is revealed in the OP's question.

As has been mentioned, `Thread[xxx -> {3, 4}]` evaluates to the intended replacements `{xxx1 -> 3, xxx2 -> 4}`. I use it quite a lot in plane graphics, usually in the slightly different form `Thread[{x, y} -> point]`, where `point` is the list of coordinates of some point.

**(3)** Another approach, which is not a perfect example of the general principal above, might get closer to what one might intend function `fsquared` to do.  One might be thinking that when `fsquared` is given a list of numbers, then evaluate; otherwise, wait.  Here is one way do that:

```
ClearAll[fsquared];
fsquared[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := x^2
```

Then `fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}` will evaluate to `{9, 16}`.  However, `fsquared[{1, 2}] /. {1, 2} -> {3, 4}` will fail to alter `fsquared[{1, 2}]`.

**(4)** One more extra.  I forget how useful [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) is on these simple examples.  But it's not easy to use, because it can be hard to keep track of all those nested braces.  WReach wrote a couple of [`traceView`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29340#29340) functions that make it easier to read the results.

We can easily see just what happens in the OP's failed case.  I recommend this to anyone who does not understand why something did not evaluate the way they thought it would. It is probably not touted enough. (Beware plotting functions, though: lots of output.)

```
ClearAll[fsquared];
fsquared[x_List] := x^2;
Block[{xxx},
 xxx = {xxx1, xxx2};
 traceView2[
  fsquared[xxx] /. xxx -> {3, 4}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see the four major steps: Evaluate the head `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), evaluate `fsquared[xxx]`, evaluate the rule `xxx -> {3, 4}`, and finally apply the rule to the function value.  Click on the [`OpenerView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenerView.html) triangles to examine the evaluation of the subexpressions.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

```
f[x_List] := x^2
f[xxx]
(* f[xxx] *)
xxx = {xxx1, xxx2};
f[xxx]
(* {xxx1^2, xxx2^2} *)
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[xxx]
(* f[xxx] *)
```

That's half the problem solved, `xxx` is held to let us replace it. However:

```
ReplaceAll[f[xxx], xxx -> {3, 4}]
```

evaluates to

```
ReplaceAll[f[xxx], {xxx1, xxx2} -> {3, 4}]
```

and no match is found. You can instead use

```
ReplaceAll[f[xxx], HoldPattern[xxx] -> {3, 4}]
```

The evaluation of `f[xxx]` is suppressed, as `f` is designed to act only on lists and the held `xxx` is not yet a list. Evaluation of `xxx` in the rule is suppressed by `HoldPattern`, finally `{3, 4}` is injected in place of `xxx` and `f` can finally evaluate. But now by adding the `HoldAll` attribute we've broken the evaluation of `f[xxx]`, we won't get a possibly desired `{xxx1^2, xxx2^2}`.

One alternative approach is not to set `HoldAll`, but to simply do a `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` wrapper:

```
ReleaseHold@ReplaceAll[Hold[f[xxx]], HoldPattern[xxx] -> {3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {9, 16}
> ```