# Why can't I pattern match Dt?

Tags: pattern-matching

A simple question:

```
MatchQ[f[a], f[x_]]
(* True *)

MatchQ[D[a], D[x_]]
(* True *)

MatchQ[Dt[a], Dt[x_]]
(* False *)
```

Why doesn't the last test succeed? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? (Mathematica 10.2 on Mac.)

Comment: Maybe because `D[a]` evaluates to `a` and `Dt[a]` does not evaluate?

Comment: @yarchik Not really. -- In `MatchQ`, the second argument is not held; it is evaluated (see the output of `Trace`). Thus, `Dt[x_]` is evaluated, creating this weird expression: `Dt[x]*Derivative[1, 0][Pattern][x, _]`. (`Dt` tries to take the derivative of the `Pattern` function) Of course `Dt[a]` looks nothing similar to this, so `MatchQ` returns `False`. I believe this is unintended (perhaps `MatchQ` should have `HoldRest` attribute).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The symbol `MatchQ` does not have an `Hold*` attribute,

```
Attributes[MatchQ]
(* {Protected} *)
```

so its arguments are evaluated before the internal definition of `MatchQ` fires. This means that the pattern-matcher is called only *after* the evaluation of the arguments. *(See for instance the standard evaluation sequence in this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html).)*

---

**First situation**

```
MatchQ[f[a], f[x_]]
(* True *)
```

The evaluation of each argument returns the argument itself, so you are effectively asking for a match between the typed expression.

---

**Second situation**

```
MatchQ[D[a], D[x_]]
(* True *)
```

The arguments are evaluated to what they contain, so you are asking for a match between `a` and `x_`, which returns `True`.

---

**Last situation**

```
MatchQ[Dt[a], Dt[x_]]
(* False *)
```

While the argument `Dt[a]` remains unchanged, the argument `Dt[x_]` gets evaluated to:

```
Dt[x] Derivative[1, 0][Pattern][x, _]
```

which then results in `False` once the pattern-matcher is called.

The fact that `Dt[x_]` evaluates to this output can be understood by seeing the symbol `Pattern` as an inert head in the evaluation sequence. You would obtain an output with the same structure by evaluating for instance `Dt[f[x, 1]]`.

This is what happens: *a)* `x_` is represented internally as `Pattern[x, Blank[]]`, and *b)* `Dt` takes the total derivative of this expression of head `Pattern` with respect to all variables, namely with respect to all expressions at level 1 or deeper that are `AtomQ` and have head `Symbol`,

```
Level[Pattern[x, Blank[]], {1}]
(* {x, _} *)

AtomQ /@ %
(* {True, False} *)

Head /@ %%
(* {Symbol, Blank} *)

Level[Pattern[x, Blank[]], {2}]
(* {} *)
```

so here only with respect to `x`.

---

**Solution**

To avoid the evaluation of the second argument, you can wrap it into [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html):

```
MatchQ[Dt[a], HoldPattern[Dt[x_]]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Nice. For tracking down such things when one is confused, `Trace[]` or especially [WReach's traceView functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/4999) can help show a user where his or her assumptions about evaluation diverge from reality.