# Serious regression in Integrate in 11.1.1? Division by zero generated

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

seen first in 11.1.1, Fixed in **11.2**

---

What is going on here?  In version 11.1.1 on windows 7

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Using Version 11.0.1 also on windows 7

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Source code

```
ClearAll[x, n, c, a ,b]
Integrate[(a + b*(c*x^n)^(2/n))^3, x]
```

Why does Mathematica give `1/0` now in the latest update? Do you think this is a new bug?

Comment: If you want, you can try [`traceView2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence)`[
Trace[Integrate[(a + b*(c*x^n)^(2/n))^3, x], TraceInternal -> True]]` to find out where things go wrong.

Comment: Slightly more minimal example triggering the bug: `Integrate[(1 + (x^n)^(-n^(-1)))^2, x]`

Comment: @QuantumDot  Yes, I found many more little simpler examples. This one also triggers it:  `Integrate[(a+(c*x^n)^(2/n))^3,x]`  but changing to `Integrate[(a+(c*x^n)^(1/n))^3,x]` and error goes away!  I just copied the one from the file I was running and posted that. I get more integrals now with same error. But I am sure they are all due to same bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, this is a bug. It actually dates to 11.1.0.  I checked with the relevant developer.  We have a fix in our internal development build, and we'll try to get it into the next release.

This is one of those funny cases where a bugfix elsewhere caused a slightly different path to be traversed inside Integrate, and that path was missing a check for division by zero.

Answer (score 5):

fyi; This bug is now fixed in 11.2. Thank you WRI

[image: Mathematica graphics]