# Is there packages can help read, analyze or understand MMA codes?

Tags: programming, core-language, language-design

Sometimes, I think that it's difficult to learn high level codes, or even when looking back on some long lines of codes I myself had written, espectially when lots of pure-functions was used, so I'm wondering that is there packages can help read, analyze or understand the structure\purpose of codes' segments, although MMA has dynamic explanation on functions,but that's not enough in large scale. 
i.e.

```
ToString /@ Table[Random[], {100}] // Style[#, Red] &
```

If the upper code could be marked like this, it would be easy to understand the computation process priorities.

```
Needs["RAUPackages`"](*fake*)
RAUParse["ToString /@ Table[Random[], {100}] // Style[#, Red] &",{"/@","//"}]
```

`RAUParse` shall output lines with underlines and sequence numbers like this. better in colors:
$$\underline{\underline{ToString /@ \underline{Table[Random[], {100}]}_1 }_2// Style[\#, Red]}_3$$
Hope there be this kind packages could take the ability!
Please show your opinion if keeping similar ideas to advance the subject.

Comment: What exactly do you want to highligh? p.s. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29339/5478

Comment: @Kuba The result produced by `TracePrint` is too detailed to read through, I want to understand program lines.

Comment: Maybe https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/5478?

Comment: I understand you would like to have an IDE that marks especial words, iddents parts inside parts, and why not help with the options a instruction has and can select beetwen them       this system nf notebooks   pretends to arrive to this but has limits, It'l be a suggestion to Wolfram

Comment: @AnxonPués If it could be integrated with MMA will be great.

Comment: @Jerry and this kind of help that closes the [ or { pr ( or <|   whith the paired ones   this is spacially helpful for ppl like me that need to compose those signs with the alt gr  // whe need several keys to produce diacritics, spacial letters like ñ ç ¿¡ ...

Comment: Here is what I think: if none of answers in linked topics fits your needs then the  answer is 'it does not exist'. And if you want it to exist you need to make a more precise question and really make sure it is answerable without doubts. Unfortunately SE is not meant for sharing ideas and discussions. You could start that project in community.wolfram.com otoh. What's your opinion on my opinion? :)