# Displaying outcome of Trace

Tags: debugging

Is there a better way to display Trace output? Parsing could be provided to separate blocks of the computation by an extra line. Trace produces a large chunk of unbroken output that I copy into a new Mathematica window and need to parse manually to display the result in more readable format.

Surely, Mathematica must come with a feature that ensures this and other debug features? If so, can you point me in the right direction? I found a link to the DebugTrace package online, but this only goes up to version 9 of Mathematica.

Comment: I downloaded the Mathematica Workbench, I hope it will resolve my issues. I am open to advice on whether this is a good solution, or links that could point me to other resources that may be better. Also see kglr's link suggested above for alternative Trace implementations. Very nice display when compared to the original.

Comment: seen [this answer by WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/125)?

Comment: Thanks kglr, my code has grown and any help to debug will be great. I'll try this first as I have no experience with eclipe.

Comment: Works great, appreciate traceview2 in particular.