# Use method "ExactAlgebraics" of PossibleZeroQ for Series zero test

Tags: series-expansion, options, algebra

I am trying to compute a series expansion around infinity with very large numerical, but entirely algebraic coefficients, and I keep running into zero test errors, which look exactly like the ones from `PossibleZeroQ`.

Using the example from the `PossibleZeroQ` documentation,

```
a = Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] - RootReduce[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]] + 10^-10000;

PossibleZeroQ[a]
```

> ```
> PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 
>     1/(10000<<9658>>000000)+Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]-Root[1-10 Slot[<<1>>]^2+#1^4&,4,0] is equal to zero. 
>     Assuming it is.
>
> True (* Wrong *)
> ```

an example series would be

```
Series[a+1/x,{x,Infinity,1}]
```

> ```
> Series::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 
>     1/(10000<<9658>>000000)+Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]-Root[1-10 Slot[<<1>>]^2+#1^4&,4,0] is equal to zero. 
>     Assuming it is.
>
> 1/x + O[1/x^2] (* Also wrong *)
> ```

`PossibleZeroQ` has the option `Method->"ExactAlgebraics"`, which gives a provably correct answer for algebraic expressions, and it tends to be very efficient for even large expressions.

```
 PossibleZeroQ[a,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Is there any way to set up Mathematica, such that the same method is also used for zero tests in `Series`?

**Edit**

I tried the method suggested by Michael, and it does work for the example I used above. However, this does not seem to work reliably. Using an example from my code,

```
longExpr = CloudGet[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/78fc84e0-083f-424f-9707-86ba0cd83ce3"]];

ClearSystemCache[];

With[{opts = Options@PossibleZeroQ},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"],
        Series[longExpr + 1/x, {x, Infinity, 1}],
    SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ, opts]]
]
```

> ```
> Series::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity **longExpr** is equal to zero. Assuming it is.
>
> 1/x + O[1/x^2]
> ```

which happens to be correct in this case. Calling `PossibleZeroQ` directly however does not throw the error

```
ClearSystemCache[];

PossibleZeroQ[longExpr,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

How could this be explained?

Comment: Would this approach be helpful?: `a0 = Limit[longExpr + 1/x, x -> Infinity];
FullSimplify[a0] + Series[longExpr + 1/x - a0, {x, Infinity, 1}]`

Comment: I only used the function `longExpr + 1/x` as an example, unfortunately I have to deal with much more complicated functions in my code. Also `FullSimplify` could probably take a very long time if the expression is not actually zero (I am actually quite surprised how fast it is for `longExpr`)

Comment: If they're algebraic numbers, you might try `RootReduce`.  For instance, `longExpr + 1/x // RootReduce` is much faster than `FullSimplify`.  Perhaps reducing the numbers are they are being built up might be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetOptions` is a way:

```
ClearSystemCache[]; (* needed if you already did Series[a +...] *)
With[{opts = Options@PossibleZeroQ},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"],
  Series[a + 1/x, {x, Infinity, 1}],
  SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ, opts]
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> (*
>   1/(1000 <<9993>> 0000) + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] - Root[1 - 10 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]) +
>    1/x +O[1/x]^2
> *)
> ```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. This method to set options locally is definitely something that will come in handy in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not always seem to work. I posted an example as an edit in my question.

Comment: @Hausdorff I get an error retrieving `longExpr`: `CloudGet::notperm: Unable to perform the requested operation. Permission denied.`

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Wolfram Cloud objects before. I think I now set it to be public.

Comment: @Hausdorff  I can't figure it out.  `Series` does not appear in a `Trace` to call `PossibleZeroQ` directly, although it evaluates its `Options`.  Possibly the call is hidden from `Trace`, but `PossibleZeroQ` works on `longExpr`; so I think there is an internal routine that might have limitations built in, such as on the size of the expression or the time to try to simplify, but I have not discovered such a routine.

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying. I really, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to understand better how Mathematica evaluates `Series`, and here I just collect some notes about what I found. I suppose this is mostly for my own reference, but perhaps somebody else may find this useful, should they stumble over a similar problem.

It is all a little speculative, as the `Series` function is mostly opaque. If anybody has any more insights, I would be really grateful. Also please let me know if any of the things I wrote below is wrong.

First off, to address the issues at hand regarding the use of the option `"ExactAlgebraics"` for zero tests in `Series`:

### TL;DR

I don't think it is currently possible to make Mathematica use the `"ExactAlgebraics"` consistently for all zero tests of series coefficients, as `PossibleZeroQ` is never actually used. However it seems there are special cases, such as coefficients containing `Root` objects, in which `Series` adheres to the `Method` option of `PossibleZeroQ`.

### How does Mathematica compute series expansions?

To look at the inner workings of `Series`, I found the tools  [`traceView`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/73380) and [`Spelunk`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/73380) to be really helpful. The [`PrintDefinitions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/73380) function of the built-in package `GeneralUtilities` is also very nice. In `traceView` I used the option `TraceInternal->True` to see as much of the internal evaluations as possible.

When calling `Series`, the function and arguments are quickly passed on to the function `` System`Private`InternalSeries ``, which then does the heavy lifting. This function has some explicit definitions for special functions, which can see be seen with `PrintDefinition` after evaluating `Series` once and calling `` ClearAttributes[System`Private`InternalSeries,ReadProtected] ``. However, for the generic case it is a kernel function, making it mostly opaque. `TraceInternal->True` still reveals some hints about its behavior.

### When does Mathematica check for coefficients to be zero?

Here we only need to look at the handling of sums during the series expansion.

When `InternalSeries` is called on a sum, Mathematica maps `InternalSeries` over the separate summands. If the expansion is around infinity, it then picks out the highest power in the expansion variable of all the summand expansions, collects every coefficient of that order, and then checks whether this coefficient is zero. If it is not zero, `Series` does not perform any further checks, and returns the series. Should the coefficient of the highest power be zero, it moves on to the next highest, repeating the process until it finds the highest power with non-zero coefficient. Notably, it does not check, whether any of the lower powers are zero.

For completeness, let's look at an example. Consider the expansion of `a + b + c/x` around $x=\infty$ up to order $\mathcal{O}\left(\tfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$. Mathematica first computes the expansion of every summand, i.e. `a + O[1/x^2]`, `b + O[1/x^2]` and `c/x O[1/x^2]`. It determines the highest power, here $\tfrac{1}{x^0}$, and performs its zero test on the coefficient, which in this case is `a + b`. If `a + b` is found to be non-zero, `Series` returns `a + b + c/x + O[1/x^2]`, even if `c` is actually zero.

### How does Mathematica check, whether a coefficient is zero?

`Series` uses a multistep process for the zero test. Looking at the traces the behavior is very closely related to that of `PossibleZeroQ`. One can also see in the trace of `Series` that in fact the default assumptions of `PossibleZeroQ` are being used, as there is a call

```
Assumptions /. Options[PossibleZeroQ]
```

so there definitely appears to be a connection. **However `PossibleZeroQ` itself never seems to be called explicitly.**

To see whether a coefficient is zero, it is first evaluated numerically at `$MachinePrecision`. Should the result be inconclusive, the coefficient is reevaluated using the precision of `$MaxExtraPrecision`. If the result is still inconclusive, `InternalSeries` generically stops here and assumes the coefficient to be zero, returning the warning `Series::ztest1`.

However, `InternalSeries` does appear to scan the expression of the coefficient for certain objects, and can enter a different branch for the zero test. One example of an object that is treated specially is `Root`. In this case one can see that `Series` does not only read in the assumptions of `PossibleZeroQ`, but also the specified method, since the trace then also shows

```
Method /. Option[PossibleZeroQ]
```

Now, after the numeric tests fail, and if `OptionValue[PossibleZeroQ,Method]` has been set to `"ExactAlgebraics"`, `InternalSeries` performs additional steps, such as using `Factor`, in line with the behavior of `PossibleZeroQ[#,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]`.

This is the reason why the solution of Michael to set the default option `Method` of `PossibleZeroQ`  worked for the example from the `PossibleZeroQ` documentation. However, in the case of my expression `longExpr`, which contains only square roots and rationals, this branch of `InternalSeries` is *not* used. Setting the `Method` option does nothing in this case, as it is never even checked.

I have not investigated further, which objects other than `Root` receive this special treatment. Anything that is guaranteed to return an algebraic number would be an obvious initial guess.

### Work-arounds

As far as I can see there are two options to get around this problem:

If in an expansion around infinity the highest order is known, one could add a non-trivial zero involving `Root` at that order. My example involving `longExpr` could be modified by adding the zero `Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] - RootReduce[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]]`, so that

```
ClearSystemCache[];
With[{opts=Options@PossibleZeroQ},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"],
        Timing@Series[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] - RootReduce[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]] + longExpr+1/x,{x,Infinity,1}],
    SetOptions[PossibleZeroQ,opts]]
]
```

> ```
> {69.5388, 1/x + O[1/x^2]} (* no Series::ztest1 message *)
> ```

The runtime is comparable to that of `PossibleZeroQ`,

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Timing@PossibleZeroQ[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] - RootReduce[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]] + longExpr,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]
```

> ```
> {66.1458, True}
> ```

but it is significantly slower than it would be without `Root`,

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Timing@PossibleZeroQ[longExpr,Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]
```

> ```
> {2.40949, True}
> ```

The other work-around would be to imitate `InternalSeries`, by mapping `Series` over the sum, extracting the highest coefficient, then explicitly using `PossibleZeroQ` to check for zeroes, and rebuilding the final `SeriesData` object from those of the summands. This option is also not ideal, as it essentially only works if the original expression is already in the form of a Taylor/Laurent series. However, this method could be used, when defining a custom series expansion which  is based on Mathematica's `Series` and `SeriesData`.

### Conclusion

Since `PossibleZeroQ` does not seem to be explicitly called in `Series`, I would guess `InternalSeries` never uses the function `PossibleZeroQ`, and it rather calls the associated internal kernel functions directly. It does seem a bit weird that `Series` respects the options set for `PossibleZeroQ`, but only when *it* decides that this might be useful. This could just be an oversight in the design of `Series`, as I am considering a bit of an edge case here, or there may be examples where using `"ExactAlgebraics"` generally might be a bad idea (though I would not know what they are).

In any case, I think letting the user decide via a `ZeroTest` option would be a really nice functionality.