# "Ordering " command gives different order when n=1 vs n=2?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, example

Heres an MWE

```
Sort[{1, 2, .1, 0, -2, 3}, If[#1 > 0, #1 < #2, False] &]

(*{0.1,1,2,3,-2,0}*)

Ordering[{1, 2, .1, 0, -2, 3}, 1, If[#1 > 0, #1 < #2, False] &]

(*{6}*)

Ordering[{1, 2, .1, 0, -2, 3}, 2, If[#1 > 0, #1 < #2, False] &]

(*{3,1}*)
```

Why is there this behavior? Specifically, why is ordering not giving the position of the first element of `Sort`, when I ask for only the first element?

Note: I believe Ordering works correctly, when all elements of the list are $>0$, so the sorting function is perhaps the issue somehow.

Edit: Using

```
Ordering[{1, 2, .1, 0, -2, 3}, 1, 
 If[#1 > 0 && #2 > 0, #1 < #2, If[#1 > 0 && #2 <= 0, True, False]] &]
```

fixes it (for the MWE at least). I figured out that the `If` statement was throwing false when I did not expect it to due to the order of comparisons.

**However** I am still not sure why, in the original case, using there was not a problem for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trace`, or [`traceView2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29340#29340),
will show the evaluations of the ordering function. It also confirms Lukas Lang's analysis of `Ordering[list, 1, func]`.

One might try to infer the algorithm for `n > 1`:

[image]

The first two steps are the same as Lukas points out for `n = 1`.  From this point, the difference will be that `Ordering` will construct a complete order instead of just finding the "minimum" (according to the ordering function). Thus the third step completes the order of `{1, 2, 0.1}` by comparing the last pair of the first three elements, `0.1` and `1`.
The next two steps construct a partial order of the remaining three elements, and the 6th step completes the order of `{0, -2, 3}`.
The last step compares the maximal element of `{1, 2, 0.1}` and the minimal element of `{0, -2, 3}`, which completes the order of all the elements.

As Lukas has mentioned, if the ordering function satisfied the conditions for an ordering function (for instance, the transitive property), there is no need to compare further pairs of elements.  In this case, if the list of numbers is shuffled, you can get different results.

Code:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{
    Labeled[
     Graph[vv, Take[cmps, steps], 
      VertexLabels -> 
       Thread[vv -> Thread[Subscript[vv, Range@Length@vv]]],
      EdgeLabels -> 
       Take[Thread[cmps ->
          (Framed[Style[#, Red], Background -> LightBlue] & /@ 
            Range@Length@cmps)], steps],
      ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> {350, 350}],
     Row[{"Next: ", 
       ReplacePart[RotateLeft@cmps, -1 -> "End"][[steps]]}],
     Top],
    Column[{" Steps "}~Join~Take[cmps, steps]]
    }}, Alignment -> Top, Dividers -> Center],
 {{n, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, TrackingFunction -> (trackFN[#] &)},
 {{steps, 1}, 1, Dynamic@Length[cmps], 1},
 {{vv, {1, 2, .1, 0, -2, 3}}, None},
 {{cmps, cmps}, None}, {{trackFN, trackFN}, None},
 Initialization :> (
   trackFN = Function[n1,
     n = n1;
     cmps = Reap[
        Ordering[vv, n,
         With[{res = If[#1 > 0, #1 < #2, False]}, 
           If[res, Sow@DirectedEdge[#1, #2], 
            Sow[DirectedEdge[#2, #1]]]; res] &]
        ][[2, 1]];
     steps = Length@cmps;
     steps];
   trackFN[1])
 ]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

In short: Your ordering function is not a valid ordering function: Both `func[-2,3]` and `func[3,-2]` return `False`, so the two numbers cannot be sorted. Sorting-related functions might therefore return unexpected results.

As for the particular result you are seeing here: My guess is that `Ordering[list, 1, func]` calls a specialized implementation for improved performance. That implementation probably goes through the list once, keeping the minimal element (and its index): So it first calls `func[1, 2]` which in your case is `True` so `1` is before `2`. Then it does `func[1,0.1]` which is `False`, so `0.1` comes before `1`. It then continues with  `func[0.1,0]` (`False`), `func[0, -2]` (`False`), and finally `func[-2,3]` which is also `False`, so `3` is before `-2` and thus `Ordering`concludes that `3` is the first element.

Comment: The key point here: "the ordering function is not a valid ordering function". If the ordering function isn't a proper ordering function then you shouldn't expect anything ordering related to be consistent for it

Comment: About your second paragraph, I understand that. My question is specifically about -- and perhaps I could have made this more clear -- `Ordering[list,1,p]` and `Ordering[list,2,p]` give different smallest elements in the supplied MWE (with the former being inconsistent with the result from `Sort`). That is... somehow the (reported) "first" element is different when changing the 1 to a 2. I do recognize that what b3m2a1 pointed out does answer this though, albeit in a broad sense.

Comment: @user106860 as I've noted, my guess is that `Ordering` is special-cased for `n=1` for increased performance, hence the different result.