# See how Mathematica computed the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, debugging

Mathematica says that the following complicated integral is infinity, which is reasonable:

```
    Integrate[((11/10)^(2/5)*Abs[t2/t1]^(1/5)*
    Abs[-t1 + (10/11)*(-1 - t1 + t2)]^(1/5))/
     (Abs[t1 - t2]^(2/5)*Abs[-1 - t1 + t2]^(2/5)*
    Abs[-t2 + (10/11)*(-1 - t1 + t2)]^(1/5)), 
   Element[{t1, t2}, 
  ImplicitRegion[t2 < (10/11)*(-1 - t1 + t2) < t1 < 0, {t1, t2}]]]
```

I want to understand **why** the result is $\infty$. I used `Trace` command, but it gives a non-useful result as follows:

[image]

How can I get more detailed steps?

Comment: Can you post the InputForm of your input? Your code is not readable as is. Trace is not really useful for finding flow of logic of a function. Hard to read and figure what it all means.

Comment: @Nasser Sure, I edited the question. If `Trace` is not useful, then what are other standard options?

Comment: [There](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence)  are better traces and use option `TraceInternal->True`

Comment: If you want to know why the improper integral under consideration diverges, then the integration of the term `Abs[t2/t1]^(1/5)` over the unbounded region of the integration (see `Reduce[t2<(10/11)*(-1-t1+t2)<t1<0,Reals]`) causes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Trace`:

```
Trace[(* integral *), TraceInternal->True]
```

You can find some better trace(more human readable)
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence). Note in most cases, sizes of trace results are very large(hundreds of MB). So it's not a good idea to view them in your notebook. Try to open them in some text editor.

2. Internal debug messages of `Integrate`.

```
Block[
    {
         Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch = 10,
         $Output = OpenWrite[
              (*log file location*)]
     }
     (*integral*);
     Close@$Output;
];
Import[(*log file location*), "Text"]
```

But notice since `Integrate` has code(i.e., has kernel definitions) and we can't view comments in source codes through public definitions(i.e., DownValues), this log may be very hard to understand...