# Define a delayed function depending on a global variable as though the variable's contents was pasted

Tags: functions, evaluation, expression-manipulation, variable, assignment

## Problem

Say I previously defined a variable (maybe through some extensive calculation)

```
thing = (a+x)y
```

Then, I want to use that expression elsewhere. In general, I can't just type "thing".
For example, the following doesn't work

```
thingy[a_,y_] := NIntegrate[ thing ,{x,0,10}]
```

## What I want

**I want a way to use variables such that it always behaves like I copied and pasted its contents directly** e.g. I want to type:

```
thingy[a_,y_] := NIntegrate[ Paste[thing] ,{x,0,10}]
```

and have it behave like:

```
thingy[a_,y_] := NIntegrate[ (a+x)y ,{x,0,10}]
```

Not just in this particular example, but in all use cases.

## What I am not looking for

Making this use case work.

Yes, I know that I can fix it with:

```
thingy[a1_,y1_] := NIntegrate[ thing /. {a->a1,y->y1} ,{x,0,10}]
```

I'd like a built-in function, even if it behaves slightly differently from the way I described, rather than a hard-coded user-defined function (unless it's a very short).

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking for, the answer is "no". Variables don't really hold any contents. The Set (=) construct creates a rewrite rule in the environment. `thing` doesn't really have a value, it's not a reference to a memory location, for example. It's just something that the evaluator will replace according to the rewrite rule. Having said that, if the evaluator is running and encounters `thing`, it will immediately replace it, which is effectively "pasting its contents". However...

Comment: Just in case this might be what you want, there is an Iconize feature. If you select your `(a+x) y` expression and bring up the context menu, you can choose to iconize it. There is also the `Iconize` symbol. You can copy/paste this thing around the notebook.

Comment: So, for examle, execute `Iconize[(a + x) y, "thing"]`. Now you can copy/paste that icon into your NIntegrate expression. It'll look like a little gray thing labeled "thing", but it will really be the expression `(a+x)y`.

Comment: @lericr that looks like a pretty good answer

Comment: @userrandrand reading through the post again, I think maybe you're right. I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @user293787 yes I meant with underscores. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: As the question is a common issue it might be helpful for other people searching for this problem to include the use case in the title. For example "define function using SetDelayed with a global variable as though it was pasted"

Answer (score 4):

3 possibilities:

- `InputAutoReplacements`
- `Inactive`/`Activate`
- `$PreRead`

the last I am less sure is safe as I never used that.

---

**1st possibility :** [`InputAutoReplacements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html)

**Edit**

You can use [`InputAliases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases.html) or [`InputAutoReplacements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html). I do not see why one would want to use `InputAliases` here so we can consider `InputAutoReplacements`.

The code:

```
thing = a + b y;
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"pastedthing" -> ToString@thing}]
```

[image: pasting_code_by_writing]

---

**2nd possibility :** [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)/[`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html)

In this case one could use (note that I used = instead of :=):

```
thing = (a + x) y;
thingy[a_, y_] = NIntegrate[thing, {x, 0, 10}] // Inactivate

thingy[4, 8]
```

`(* Inactive[NIntegrate][8 (4 + x), {x, 0, 10}] *)`

Notice that the integrand has been evaluated which I feel is more pleasant than using  [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html).

then

```
thingy //Activate
```

`(* 720. *)`

(* Note: see @att's suggestion to use `Activate` on the [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `thingy` *)

Check that the result is the same as using `NIntegrate` directly:

```
NIntegrate[8 (4 + x), {x, 0, 10}]
```

`(* 720. *)`

If writing Inactive[NIntegrate] each time is tedious you could add
nintegrate=Inactive[NIntegrate] to your init.m file (some people do not recommend this as you will likely forget what you put there and could cause issues with some code 3 months from now).

---

**3rd possibility:** [`$PreRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PreRead.html)

Another possibility which I have never used before, so it might cause issues, is to define a function for $PreRead to set up an alias between the character "thing" and it's evaluated output  :

```
$PreRead = ReplaceAll[#, "thing" -> ToString[thing]] &
```

Then you can use

```
thingy[a_, y_] := NIntegrate[thing, {x, 0, 10}];

thingy[4, 3]
```

270. 

One issue with doing that is that you will not be able to clear the variable using:

```
Clear[thing]
```

Because Mathematica will see the evaluated form

```
Clear[(a + x) y];
```

Probably also a lot of the functions that have `Attribute` `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll` will not work as expected. As such it might be better to use a different name for the alias than for the expression to remember what we are doing when we type.

Comment: Worth noting that `=` is required because `:=` does not evaluate its right hand side (and thus won't perform variable substitutions). It's probably more convenient to append `//Inactivate` to the definition instead of wrapping heads present there with `Inactive`, and this step can be entirely skipped if delayed evaluation of the RHS isn't needed.

Comment: You can also `DownValues[thingy] = Activate@DownValues[thingy]` afterwards to remove the need to `Activate` the function result.

Comment: @att I agree that `Inactive[NIntegrate]` is tedious to write but it allows the integrand to be evaluated without the integral being evaluated. I find that a bit pleasant to see when calling the function without `Activate` .  Also using `nintegrate=Inactive[NIntegrate]`  makes it less tedious to write

Comment: `Inactivate`ing the whole expression more closely mirrors the semantics of the original `:=` assignment, but I definitely see the argument in favor of only `Inactive`ating some heads.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, `Activate[Inactivate[definition]]` pretty much satisfies OP's requirements.

Comment: @att I have not tested the  `DownValues[thingy] = Activate@DownValues[thingy]` trick but it seems pretty cool I will hopefully remember to try it out.Thanks (:

Comment: @att maybe you might want to post `Activate[Inactivate[definition]]` idea i am not sure what you have in mind. I updated my answer to also use `$PreRead` to make an input alias

Comment: @att even if one evaluates the right hand side of := using `With` the pattern values on the left hand side will change maybe to avoid problems with localization of the arguments of the function. That can be checked by using `With[{thing=thing},thingy[a_,y_]:= ... thing ..  ]` and then checking the down values of thingy. As such I rather not get into the details of why := will not work like = especially that I am not sure or do not remember all the details.

Comment: @att is the "definition" here the RHS, or the whole expression? When you say `Activate[Inactivate[definition]]`

Comment: @IonSme hi att posted their answer with what they meant.

Comment: @att I tried Activate@DownValues[thingy] and It did not activate the `Inactivate`

Comment: @userrandrand you need to assign `DownValues[thingy]=Activate@DownValues[thingy]`.

Comment: @att I know maybe I miss understood the `//Inactivate` and you meant to use `Inactivate[thingy[a_]:=thing]` while I understood that you meant `thingy[a_]:=thing//Inactivate` which after rereading your comment you did say `append //Inactivate to the **definition**` so maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @userrandrand My original suggestion was to `Inactivate` the RHS (`//` has higher precedence than `:=`) instead of manually `Inactive`-ing certain heads, after which the downvalues can be activated as described.

Comment: @att What I did : `thing = (a + x) y;
thingy[a_, y_] := NIntegrate[thing, {x, 0, 10}] // Inactivate` then `DownValues[thingy] = Activate@DownValues[thingy]` and that did not work

Comment: @userrandrand Oops, I meant `=`. As noted in my first comment this kind of construction relies on using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @att ooh now I understand sorry my mistake. Thanks for the tip and help (:.

Answer (score 3):

I'm keying off of the copy/paste idea that you emphasize. You might be interested in Iconize. Let's say you did that complicated calculation and saved it to `thing`. We'll let this represent that situation:

```
thing = (a + x) y
```

Now you can do either of these:

```
Iconize[(a + x) y, "thing"]
Iconize[thing, "thing"] (* since Iconize doesn't hold its arguments unevaluated *)
```

As the output you'll see an icon, like a token. It will be labeled *thing*, and the actual expression will be hidden. You can expand it to see some meta data. The important thing here is that whatever interactions you do with this icon/token will work pretty much as if you were interacting with the full expression directly. In particular, you can copy/paste this thing and the effect is the same as if you had copy/pasted the entire expression. By giving it the label "thing", it kind of looks like the symbol `thing`.

Comment: This does make copying and pasting less horrible looking,  but I still have to use copy and paste. I.E the following does not work `thing = a + b y ;`
`thing = Iconize[thing,"thing"];`
`thingy[a_,b_,y_] =thing;`

Comment: I didn't want to actually paste things because I can't edit previous code, and then rerun the whole document. Is there a way to use this technique but avoid having to actually copy paste?

Comment: Look at userrandrand's updated answer. I think InputAliases or InputAutoReplacements might be what you want.

Comment: I think you'll need to define them for some context (e.g. current notebook or global or whatever) via the options inspector, so it's not as dynamic as, say, the Iconize idea. In other words, it's a front end thing, not a Wolfram Language thing. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I just want to be able to copy and paste complicated expressions from previous calculations,  without it (1)  being hardcoded and (2) looking ugly.

Comment: About (1) I want to be able to edit the previous calculations, rerun the document and have the stuff I pasted update as well.

Comment: About (2) I want to not have to type lots of stuff everywhere, and it should be easy to do freqnently.

Comment: whether its technically front or back end doesn't matter to much to me. However, if I make changes in the fron end inspector, it seems unlikely that it would satisfy (1)

Comment: @IonSme (1) By hard coded I suppose you mean that you do not want to have to set up the notebook or the evaluation process to do that automatically ? For example you do not want to change the notebook settings or change `$PreRead` ?

Comment: (2) By ugly I suppose you mean lengthy to write or adhoc looking such as `h[a1_,b1_]:=.... /.{a-a1,b->b1}` ?

Comment: Also maybe `Activate` `Deactivate` is too lengthy.

Comment: You could set up an alias for @att's solution with `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"paste" -> "Activate@Inactivate"}]`. That will only work in the current notebook. If you want it to always work in every notebook I think I vaguely know what to do but as it could mess up all of your notebooks I rather not say and would suggest to ask that in a separate question. There might be a way with the option inspector. If you do not get an answer then you can ask me and I will tell you what I think one has to do to get it to work on all the notebooks.

Comment: $PreRead I need to look at more, but if reruning the document does not update the definitions of thing, I call it hard coded. h[a1_,b1_]:=.... /.{a-a1,b->b1} is what I mean by ugly. And Activate@Deactivate is a bit long, but one of the best so far. Need to make sure there aren't some other cases where it breaks though.

Comment: $PreRead makes replacements before anything else. Mathematica still considers it a random string of text at that point so the replace function in my answer is basically doing a search and replace as one would do with "Ctrl+F" for example. Mathematica then checks for syntax errors then does some assignments to keep a record of what has happened and then evaluates and then other details.

Comment: For a clear list of the order of events each time you execute a command search (with `Ctrl+F` ) for "All Wolfram System sessions repeatedly execute the following main loop" [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GlobalAspectsOfWolframSystemSessions.html#25706)

Comment: @IonSme if you are rerunning the whole document then you should be running the `$PreRead` command too. It would only be hard coded if you explicitly wrote the characters in the expression but I used `ToString@thing` so the result depends on the expression of thing.  With Iconize you might need to re copy and paste the icon each time I do not know. The `SetOptions` will require you to remove the expression and retype "pastedthing" each time which could be tedious if you rerun the document a lot.  I personally think @att's method is the best for rerunning the document multiple times

Comment: $Preread is convenient if you define a lot of functions that use the same variable `thing` as you only have to use `$Preread` once per variable. att's method is convenient when you have many variables but few functions. My only concern with `$Preread` is that you need to use a different name than the variable you want to use and only use it for pasting when you explicitly want the expression to be there and you do not use it in an expression that temporarily or permanently hold its arguments. Basically att's method is safer and probably better.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you?

```
thing[a_, y_, x_] := (a + x) y;
thingy[a_, y_] := NIntegrate[thing[a, y, x], {x, 0, 10}];
thingy[3, 2]
(* 160 *)
```

Comment: That would be nice if I had the foresight to define thing as a function. However, oftentimes I am dealing with expressions with many variables, which I do not know a priori if they are going to be changing. Afterwards It's a little cumbersome to go back and redefine "thing" everywhere in my code.

Comment: However, oftentimes I am dealing with expressions with many variables, which I do not know a priori if they are going to be changing. Afterwards It's a little cumbersome to go back and redefine "thing" everywhere in my code.

Comment: Alternatively, I could define thing[] such that it takes as arguments every single variable in the expression, however, that's a bit ugly to have everywhere in my code, especially if it turns out that all of them are constants later.

Comment: @IonSme you could in principle define `thing` then define `auxthing[a_,b_,c_]=thing` `(= not :=)` then `thingy[a_,b_,c_]:=NIntegrate[auxthing[a,b,c],{s,0,1}]` but that would be a bit long to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can `Inactivate` the definition to resolve variables in it (if they are atomic and not a head), then immediately `Activate` it to evaluate the definition.

```
thing = (a + x) y;
Activate@Inactivate[thingy[a_, y_] := NIntegrate[thing, {x, 0, 10}]];
DownValues@thingy

    {HoldPattern[thingy[a_, y_]] :> NIntegrate[(a + x) y, {x, 0, 10}]}
```

You can wrap variables you don't wish to expand in `Inactive` to prevent unwanted substitutions.

[image: Name collision, prevented with Inactive]

---

In the original expression, since `:=` (`SetDelayed`) does not evaluate its right hand side, variables present there will not be expanded.

[image: Trace of the modified definition]

[`Inactivate[...]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) works by wrapping all heads in an expression with `Inactive`, inhibiting evaluation of those heads. Importantly, the inactivated head `Inactive[SetDelayed]` does not prevent evaluation of its right hand side. This allows evaluation to proceed into the expression, identify that `thing` evaluates to `(a + x) y`, and perform the substitution accordingly. This yields an `Inactivate`d definition where atomic variable substitutions have been made.

Finally, we `Activate` to remove the `Inactive`s and evaluate the definition.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I'm a bit confused about why.

Comment: As in why don't the activate and inactivate just cancel out?

Comment: @IonSme Some evaluation occurs between the application of `Inactivate` and `Activate`. Let me know if the edit is helpful.

Comment: @IonSme if you want to visualize the order of evaluation in mathematica you can use this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/86543). It might take some time to learn how to navigate but it gives a nice view of what happened. Using traceview2 from that answer you can use `traceView2[
 Activate@Inactivate[thingy[a_, y_] := NIntegrate[thing, {x, 0, 10}]]]` to see the evaluations in a table that you can interactively open and close.