# Why is my module saying "cannot assign to raw object" when I run it more than once?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks, homework

I am trying to solve the shortest path problem in Mathematica. My code looks like this so far. I first import the list.

```
list = Import["graph.txt", "CSV"];
```

Where list looks like this.

```
{{"node0", "node1 0.04", "node8 11.11", "node14 72.21"},
{"node1", "node46 1247.25", "node6 20.59", "node13 64.94"},
{"node2", "node66 54.18", "node31 166.80", "node45 1561.45"},
{"node3", "node20 133.65", "node6 2.06", "node11 42.43"},
```

for a hundred nodes.

Then I do this.

```
dataToMatrix[list0_] := 
 Module[{q, list = list0, graph, node, igraph , dist , i},
  q = Array[m, {100, 100}];
  graph = ToExpression[StringSplit[#] & /@ list];
  node = Table[ToExpression["node" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 99}];
  igraph = graph /. MapThread[(#1 -> #2) &, {node, Range[1, 100]}];
  dist = Select[Flatten[Module[{x}, x = #;
        Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph, 1], 
    Length@# > 1 &];
  MapThread[(#1 = #2) &, {Map[Extract[q, #] &, dist[[All, 1 ;; 2]]], 
    dist[[All, 3]]}];
  Map[If[Not[Numberq[#]], # = "."] &, Flatten@q];
  q = q /. "." -> inf;
  Return[q]]
```

Then when I run

```
dataToMatrix[list]
```

It works fine at first.

But if I run it again anywhere else, it throws

```
Set::setraw:cannot assign to raw object 0.04'.
```

repeatedly.

How do I fix this? I need to use the result from dataToMatrix in other modules.

Comment: Hi, here is a procedure to find the source of the error. Next to the error there are 3 points. Click on the 3 points then click on "Show Stack Trace". The last error shows an assignment 0.04=0.04. The error before that shows `MapThread` was making an assignment between one numerical list and another numerical list (you might want to click it to see more of it but that can cause issues with longer expressions so save the notebook before). Search for `MapThread` in your code for something strange ...

Comment: ... Notice that the first term in the list depends on `dist`. Look at `dist`, nothing obviously weird then look at `q` and notice that `m` has the color of a variable with an assigned value.

Comment: Also [Echo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html)  can be useful for showing the output of parts of code. There is also a resource function I have not tried myself but that could be interesting [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EchoIf). If all else fails you try reducing the length of the lists/expressions in the input and using the traceview2 function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/86543)

Comment: Also you do not need to use `MapThread` to set an assignment  between lists . You can use list1=list2 and then check that the variables in the lists have been assigned.

Comment: Also for setting a rule between components of lists you can use `Thread[list1->list2]` which is easier to read.