# How to fix this error : SetDelayed::write: Tag Plus in (<<1>>)[x_] is Protected.?

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

I don't get the meaning of the sign <<>> and also from which line the error is coming as I have a program of more than 30 lines with many defined functions without using "Module" . Is not there any way to display line numbers in Mathematica so that we can know from which line error is coming?

Comment: *Mathematica* is not so hot on lines and debuggging is not straightforward. Please add the offending code (or a minimal working example thereof) - without code there is no way to help you.

Comment: We need a minimal example to give a clear analysis of the problem, but the cause is likely to be very similar to this: [(11982)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982)

Comment: I didn't write Quit[] at the end of the program. That is why for the first time when I run the program I got the result, but after some modification when I run the program, I got that error message. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you used a function and then tried to manually set another value to it. for instance:

fun=3; fun[x_]:=Tan[x]; gives the following error

"SetDelayed::write: "Tag Integer in 3[x_] is Protected"

you are probably doing something very similar.

Comment: So how do you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

<< ..>> is called a Skeleton. It is is used to show you an abbreviated version of the actual offending line. You can find it in `Short` and `Shallow`.

```
Short[(x + y)^30 // Expand]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the skeleton right there in the middle.

The error message probably comes from an illegal construction like:

```
(a + b)[x_] := 2
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Plus in (a+b)[x_] is Protected. >>