# Protected Tag list and not a vector errors

Tags: vector

I am working on a project for school, and I just need to find when the angle between a tangent vector and a line formed between two points. Here is the code I'm using:

```
v[t_] = Simplify[{{0.95, 0.4, 0.35} - rsSpline[t]}];
angle[t_] = VectorAngle[rsSpline'[t], v[t]]
```

rsSpline is vector path that is defined earlier, I'll include it at the bottom. When I run this code I get a Tag list in __ is protected. Any ideas on how to get the angle[t] to be evaluated?

```
rsSpline[t_] = {Piecewise[{{0., 
  t > 20 || t < 0}, {-0.2937381672928643 + 
   0.15040714998600957*t - 0.009814309237081695*t^2 + 
   0.0002765249899592576*t^3, 
  Inequality[40/3, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 
   20]}, {0.15859527846615362 + 0.048632124690230844*t - 
   0.0021811823398982626*t^2 + 0.00008569681752967245*t^3, 
  Inequality[20/3, LessEqual, t, Less, 40/3]}}, 
0.007407407407407408 + 0.11666666666666667*t - 
 0.012386363636363633*t^2 + 0.0005959558823529409*t^3], 
Piecewise[{{0., 
  t > 20 || t < 0}, {2.3628688879724002 - 0.40432249899261*t + 
   0.03270443866666542*t^2 - 0.0009146400119319888*t^3, 
  Inequality[40/3, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 
   20]}, {0.5328657794849881 - 0.022883925511597986*t + 
   0.00864336454488792*t^2 - 0.0005404541033524712*t^3, 
  Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 20/3]}}, 
0.39814521980207296 + 0.03774032634571389*t - 
 0.0004502732337088676*t^2 - 0.00008577221442263185*t^3], 
Piecewise[{{0., 
  t > 20 || t < 0}, {-0.13132189257653604 + 
   0.1485145520804218*t - 0.013373484217090448*t^2 + 
   0.00036857764236616127*t^3, 
  Inequality[40/3, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 20]}, {0.7 - 
   0.03263184092261795*t - 0.0006726596658646056*t^2 + 
   0.00009531477478562237*t^3, 
  Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 20/3]}}, 
0.7262268125630266 - 0.04443390657597979*t + 
 0.00109765018213967*t^2 + 6.799282385408284*^-6*t^3]};
```

Comment: `v[t_] := Simplify[{0.95, 0.4, 0.35} - rsSpline[t]];
angle[t_] := VectorAngle[rsSpline'[t], v[t]]`. Note: (i) you should you SetDelayed (ii) the extra curly brackets  in v[t] definition lead to the error->remove.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you, I've fixed those but I still don't have the Tags protected fixed. I'd upvote but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: @Hovestar I have run the corrected code on a fresh session with no errors, e.g. `Table[angle[j], {j, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]` yielded {0.0887941, 0.0788714, 0.0691422, 0.0599565, 0.0519149, 0.0459925, \
0.043476, 0.0453416, 0.0514755, 0.0609099}. So, I suggest saving, quitting kernel and starting fresh session.

Comment: @ubpdqn That worked! Could you put that as an answer so I can mark this as completed?

Comment: Also related: [(11982)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v[t_] := Simplify[{0.95, 0.4, 0.35} - rsSpline[t]]; 
angle[t_] := VectorAngle[rsSpline'[t], v[t]]
```

Note: (i) you should you SetDelayed (ii) the extra curly brackets in v[t] definition lead to the error->remove

I have run the corrected code on a fresh session with no errors, e.g.

```
Table[angle[j], {j, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

yielded

```
{0.0887941, 0.0788714, 0.0691422, 0.0599565, 0.0519149, 0.0459925, 0.043476, 0.0453416, 
  0.0514755, 0.0609099}
```

So, I suggest saving, quitting kernel and starting fresh session.