# Automatically add debug contents to a program

Tags: debugging, code-generation

Sometimes I'll use `Print[1]` or `Print[n]` to debug in a long loop, but it's really a boring job to add these sentence by sentence and removing them sentence by sentence. (It's already boring to read this first three lines sentence by sentence so you can imagine how boring it is to add these stuff sentence by sentence. :P) So my question is **how to throw this job to a program?**

Let's take this small (and stupid) program as an example:

```
Do[j=i^2;Thread[{{1},{2,3}}],{i,3}]
```

I would like to add two `Print` in this program to determin where the problem occurs.

```
Do[Print@1;j=i^2;Print@2;Thread[{{1},{2,3}}],{i,3}]
```

In this way I can know that it's the second step that goes wrong.

Any idea how to do this automatically?

Comment: Workbench has such functionalities.

Comment: @happyfish I think this could be done by only Mathematica. After all, Mathematica operate on expressions and this is a part of it~

Comment: It just make things easier, another example: building documentations.

Comment: @happyfish maybe it will, but I simply don't have one :P

Comment: ahhhh sorry I didn't take this into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I checked my account's question list again and find this question lying inside. After a year wrestling mostly with `Hold` stuffs, I think I finally found a, well, not that elegant solution. Any suggestions or new answers are surely welcomed!!!

It seems that this question is not that bad, actually I may say that It's quite hard for one to solve this problem using all sorts of evaluation manipulation techniques. and it has real applications sometimes.

---

As usual, my code first:

```
SetAttributes[adddebug, HoldFirst]
adddebug[orig_, func_: Echo, level_: {2}] :=
 Module[{$count = 1, tempf},
  Replace[
    Replace[Hold[orig], HoldPattern[CompoundExpression[comp__]] :> 
      Block[{}, 
       tempf @@ 
         Riffle[List @@ (Hold /@ Hold[comp]), 
          With[{$func = func, q = #}, Hold@$func@q] & /@ 
           Range[$count, ($count = $count + Length@Hold[comp] + 1) - 
             1], {2, -1, 2}] /; True],level], 
    tempf[seg__] :> 
     Block[{}, 
      tempf[Hold[CompoundExpression]] @@ (tempf /@ {seg}) /; True],level] /. tempf[Hold[seg_]] :> seg
  ]

adddebug[Do[j = i^2; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}], {i, 3}]]
```

The result is satisfying

> Hold[Do[j = i^2; Echo[1]; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]; Echo[2], {i, 3}]]

---

Some additional notes:

Why I say this question is not that trivial is because I should protect `CompoundExpression` and its content from evaluating while still need to operate on `CompoundExpression`'s structure and use in place evaluation techniques extensively.

So I install protection in the following ways:

1. When pattern-matching, Use `HoldPattern`
2. Use unique symbol `tempf` as a medium to mark Where `CompoundExpression` previoulsly existed. **Use `tempf[Hold[CompoundExpression]]`**.
3. make every element of CompoundExpression Hold at all times, and mark them using `tempf[Hold[expr]]`
4. I'm quite satisfied by the last `ReplaceAll`'s design, as previously I’ve already make where should be `CompoundExpression` `tempf[Hold[CompoundExpression]]` and where should be `CompoundExpression`'s element `tempf[Hold[element]]`, Now I can safely use `ReplaceAll` once to make those stuffs back to their original form!

---

I still am looking foward to a better solution, so if anyone has any idea, post something, Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In your example, a message is issued at the problem.  You want to find out where the message comes from.  The debugger is pretty good at this.  Just enable the debugger, then enable Break at Messages, then evaluate your code.

[image]

- You get a nice display of the stack, which in itself allows you to localize the problem.
- Since this was an interactive evaluation, the problem is also highlighted in the notebook
- If we had a `Module` there, we could see its local variables in the Stack window, with their values.
- Evaluation is suspended in you're in a dialog. You can evaluate things and examine the kernel state.  Evaluating `i` gives `1` (even though `i` is a local variable.
- You could even put `Dynamic[i]` in a new windows and watch `i` change live as you step through the code.

In my opinion, I think the debugger is way underrated.  The big problem with it is that it has a breakpoints feature, like traditional debuggers, and people try to use this then get frustrated.  There are many reasons why breakpoints just don't fit Mathematica well.  Don't use them.  The other features work well.

When I do need a breakpoint, I explicitly insert an `Assert[False]` in the code and enable Break at Asserts.

I know this does not answer your actual question, but I hope you will still find it useful to solve your problem ...

Comment: but in my real situation I suppose I must use my approch. I'm making a ray tracer, so I need to check the behaviour of one of my light beam at each step. So I'll need to know both the step number and the beam's equation. You know, `Print` or `Echo` is always customizable while debugger is not. :P

Comment: Also, sometimes I will add something like track=1 and Dynamic@track so I can keep informed of which step is going. This is not quite easy to do in debug mode I suppose?

Comment: So how to get the Stack?

Comment: @Wjx Actually I described how to track which steps you're in inside of a `Do` ... with `Dynamic` if you like ...

Comment: Well, Seemingly I cannot find anything that cannot be done by debugger in this situation at this point......So what if I simply want to add some sentence with some pattern and thread them into this loop?

Comment: @Wjx I understand that your question is not how to debug, but how to programmatically rewrite code.  My post doesn't answer that, and in no way did I mean to imply that you *should* use the debugger instead of rewriting.  I merely wanted to point out an alternative approach to debugging which you may or may not find useful for your specific problem.

Comment: @Wjx I am not aware of any way the debugger can help with rewriting code automatically.  You *can* manually redefine things after you've entered a dialog, but that's still a manual way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually [form C.E.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119287/how-to-make-the-modulenumber-dynamic-in-a-string?noredirect=1#comment322646_119287).

Make a custom function for this

```
SetAttributes[AddPrint, HoldFirst]
AddPrint[loopBody_] := 
 Module[{st = ToString[Unevaluated[loopBody], InputForm], i = 0}, 
  StringReplace[st, 
   RegularExpression["^|(?<=;)"] :> TemplateApply["Print[``];", ++i]]]
```

It can help you add `Print` into your `loopBody` automatically

```
loopBody = AddPrint[j = i^2; a + b; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]]
```

> Print[1];j = i^2;Print[2]; a + b;Print[3]; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]

Answer (score 2):

I often use the form

```
Block[{Print=Identity}, expr]
```

to suppress `Print` statements that I have added for debug purposes.

Comment: That will be great. also With will do the same~ but how can we add these things?

Answer (score 1):

My code is executed in two distinct environments: inside WorkBench where I test it, and automatically by kernel. Inside WorkBench `$Linked` is `True`, so I set the following:

```
If[$Linked,
  dbPrint = Print;
];
```

Then, when I need a debug print out, I used `dbPrint` which only has a value when being run inside of WorkBench, and does not effect production code. Obviously, other environment specific code can be added to the `If` statement as needed.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't have Workbench, but I just evaluated `$Linked` in a random notebook, and it returned True. The documentation also seems to indicate that "$Linked is True when the Wolfram System is being run with a front end. ". Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @MarcoB right. In this WB acts as the FrontEnd. From what I've seen, it's set to `True` when a `$ParentLink` exists. But, don't take that as being canonical info.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mangling the code by inserting [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print)/[`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo) statements into it, you could modify [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression) during run-time. Here is a function that does this:

```
SetAttributes[injectTiming, HoldFirst]

injectTiming[code_, instance_:Automatic] := Module[{ilevel = 1, target},
    target = Replace[instance, Except[_Integer?Positive] -> 1];
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Internal`$ContextMarks=False, CompoundExpression},
        Unprotect[CompoundExpression];
        CompoundExpression[a__] /; (ilevel++ == target) := compoundExpression[a];
        code
    ]
]

SetAttributes[compoundExpression,HoldAll];

compoundExpression[a___, b_]  := Module[{last},
    Apply[
        List,
        Function[Null, Print[First @ AbsoluteTiming[#;], ": ", HoldForm[#]], HoldFirst] /@ Hold[a]
    ];
    last = AbsoluteTiming[b];
    Print[First @ last, ": ", HoldForm[b]];

    Last @ last
]
```

The second argument specifies which [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression) instance should be modified with debug information, with default being the first. For your example:

```
injectTiming[Do[j=i^2; Thread[{{1},{2,3}}], {i,3}]]
```

> 3.*10^-6: j=i^2
>
> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{1},{2,3}} cannot be combined.
>
> 0.00228: Thread[{{1},{2,3}}]
>
> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{1},{2,3}} cannot be combined.
>
> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{1},{2,3}} cannot be combined.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Thread::tdlen will be suppressed during this calculation.