# How to make the $ModuleNumber dynamic in a string

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation

This code can run normally

```
st = ToString[Unevaluated[j = i^2; a + b; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]], 
   InputForm];
i = 0; loopBody = 
 StringReplace[st, 
  RegularExpression["^|(?<=;)"] :> 
   TemplateApply["Print[<*i*>];", i++]]
```

And this is my expected answer

> "Print[1];j = i^2;Print[2]; a + b;Print[3]; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]"

So I want to pack it into a custom function like

```
SetAttributes[AddPrint, HoldFirst]
AddPrint[loopBody_] := 
 Module[{st = ToString[Unevaluated[loopBody], InputForm], i = 0}, 
  StringReplace[st, 
   RegularExpression["^|(?<=;)"] :> 
    TemplateApply["Print[<*i*>];", i++]]]
```

Then I get

```
AddPrint[j = i^2; a + b; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]]
```

> "Print[i];j = i^2;Print[i]; a + b;Print[i]; Thread[{{1}, {2, 3}}]"

I think the culprit is that `$ModuleNumber` is changing all the same.Of course we can make it like

```
SetAttributes[AddPrint, HoldFirst]
AddPrint[loopBody_] := 
 Module[{st = ToString[Unevaluated[loopBody], InputForm]}, i = 0; 
  StringReplace[st, 
   RegularExpression["^|(?<=;)"] :> 
    TemplateApply["Print[<*i*>];", i++]]]
```

But I don't like this solution.I will make `i` be global.So I want to verify any smart way can do this?

Comment: Instead of `TemplateApply` use `StringJoin["Print[", ToString[i++], "];"]`

Comment: @C.E. Good point out.Thanks. Can you post it as an answer?If there is no better way I'm going to accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace your `TemplateApply` with either

```
TemplateApply["Print[``];", i++]
```

or

```
StringJoin["Print[", ToString[i++], "];"]
```

There is also a quick fix that is not recommended, which is to replace `Module` by `Block`.