# Tag protected error for Grad despite using Unprotect[Grad]?

Tags: built-in-symbols, upvalues

I've defined an upvalue grade[k,m], where k is an integer and m is a matrix, and have defined a number of overrides for this type in the normal Mathematica namespace (`D`, `DisplayForm`, `TraditionalForm`, `StandardForm`).  If I attempt to do the same for the `Grad` function:

```
Unprotect[Grad]
Grad[m_grade, {x_, y_, z_}] := (Vector[1, 1] ** D[s, x] + Vector[1, 2] ** D[s, y] + Vector[1, 3] ** D[s, z]) // Simplify ;
Protect[Grad]
```

I get an error:

[image: Grad tag error]

This doesn't seem to be syntax error related like [How do I identify the source of a “Tag times protected” error?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error), as I can lower case my Grad function -> grad, and the error does not occur.

Shouldn't the use of `Unprotect` and `Protect` allow me to provide my own definition for Grad specific to a my `grade` type?  This seems to work for functions like DisplayForm, but not for Grad.

I note that the tag error for Grad is actually that the symbol :\nabla: is protected, and I am wondering if I need to `Unprotect`/`Protect` a symbol instead of the function name `Grad`?

I thought perhaps I could use the operator syntax that I've used to override other built in names for my type.  Example:

```
grade /: grade[ 3, s_ ] ** grade[ k_, m_ ] := grade[ 3, s ] grade[ k, m ] ;
```

(which provides a definition for the Mathematica built-in `NonCommutativeMultiply`).  However, I can't seem to figure out the right syntax for that.

Is there a way to override the gradient operation for my type without hitting this tag protected error, and why doesn't `Unprotect` work in this case?

Comment: See also: [(5649379)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5649379/618728)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of auto-loading.  Most functions aren't loaded at startup.  That would take a very long time.  They are only loaded when they are used for the first time.  To make things more complicated, using function `x` for the first time will often also load a different function `y` at the same time.

What happens here is that when `Grad` auto-loads, its `Protected` attribute is re-set.

Simply trigger loading before unprotecting it.

```
Grad (* trigger loading *)
Unprotect[Grad]
...
```

Perhaps a better and more robust solution is to associate the definition with `grade` instead.  You do this the same way as in your other example.

```
grade /: Grad[m_grade, ...] := ...
```