# How do I use Module to convert a calculation into a function?

Tags: functions, warning-messages, output

I have some code that performs a calculation. I want to make a function out of it so I wont have to cut and paste to calculations with different values of `a`, `b` and `f[x]`

---

Here is my calculation:

```
ClearAll[a, b, f, j, k, m, n, o]
f[x_] := k x^2;
a = 0;
b = 4;
j = Solve[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] == 1 && k > 0, k];
k = k /. j[[1]];
m = Integrate[f[x] x, {x, a, b}];
n = Integrate[f[x] (x - m)^2, {x, a, b}];
o = Sqrt[%];
Print["For a=", a, " and b=", b, " and f(x)=", 
 f[x], ",  the mean is ", m, ", k is ", k, ", standard deviation is \
", Sqrt[n], ", and variance is ", n, "."]
Plot[f[x], {x, If[a == Infinity, 1000, a], 
  If[b == Infinity, 1000, b]}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{m, 0}, {m, f[m]}}], 
   Line[{{m - o, 0}, {m - o, f[m - o]}}], 
   Line[{{m + o, 0}, {m + o, f[m + o]}}]}]
```

---

A *similar question* suggested that I use `Module`, but I don't know exactly to do. Which variables should I give in the first argument?

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
probabilityplot[s_, t_, fri_] := Module[{a, b, f, j, m, n, o},
  ClearAll[a, b, f, j, k, m, n, o]
    f[x_] := fri;
  a = s;
  b = t;
  j = Solve[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] == 1 && k > 0, k];
  k = k /. j[[1]];
  m = Integrate[f[x] x, {x, a, b}];
  n = Integrate[f[x] (x - m)^2, {x, a, b}];
  o = Sqrt[%];
  Print["For a=", a, " and b=", b, " and f(x)=", f[x], 
    ",  the mean is ", m, ", k is ", k, ", standard deviation is ", 
    Sqrt[n], ", and variance is ", n, "."]
   Plot[f[x], {x, If[a == Infinity, 1000, a], 
     If[b == Infinity, 1000, b]}, 
    Epilog -> {Line[{{m, 0}, {m, f[m]}}], 
      Line[{{m - o, 0}, {m - o, f[m - o]}}], 
      Line[{{m + o, 0}, {m + o, f[m + o]}}]}]
  ]

probabilityplot[0, 4, k *x^2]
```

> SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in Null f\$1252[x\$_] is Protected. >>
>   Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
>   ReplaceAll::reps: {{}[[1]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>   \$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>   Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {Indeterminate,0,4}. >>
>   \$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

[image: output]

---

I do not know what all the messages means. Please help.

Comment: Usually, the first error message is indicative of trying something weird or really involved; in this case, you are missing a semicolon after `ClearAll` (which is not needed, as a module defines its own context and localizes variables to that context); also, you need another semicolon after `Print`; the `If` statements in the `Plot` I think need to be wrapped with `Evaluate` or alternatively, move the `If` outside of `Plot`.

Comment: Lastly, replace the `%` inside `Module` with `n`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Comment: What "similar question" exactly?

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri I did as you suggest: removed ClearAll line, add the missing semicolons, replaced % with n, and also wrapped If in Evaluate. It still doesn't work. I can only make it to work if I do not put the line of codes in a Module. Otherwise, it can't compute k and display the plot. Which variables do you put on the 1st argument of Module?

Comment: What exactly 'doesn't work'? Are there error messages? Please provide a code update. Usually, in the 1-st argument of [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) you list those symbols you want to be treated as local to the module.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of minor issues with the code in the question. I address some of them in the comments.

The main issue is the attempt to define a local function, as in

```
probabilityplot[s_, t_, fri_] := Module[{},
  f[x_] := fri; 
  ...
 ]
```

This does not work, as expected. I'm not sure how to make it work as it should, but I managed to repair the code nevertheless

```
(* added Block to localize k - I understand it's awkward *)
Block[{k},
 probabilityplot[s_, t_, fri_] := Module[{a=s, b=t, f, j, m, n, o},
   (* ClearAll[a,b,f,j,k,m,n,o] - not necessary *) 

   f[x_] := fri;

   (* following two assignments not necessary *)
   (* a = s; *)
   (* b = t; *)

   (* Integrate works when fri is a function of x *)
   j = Solve[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] == 1 && k > 0, k];

   (* k is a parameter of fri *)
   k = k /. j[[1]] // N;

   (* k is now equal to a value - again Integrate works when fri is a function of x *)
   m = Integrate[f[x] x, {x, a, b}] // N;
   n = Integrate[f[x] (x - m)^2, {x, a, b}] // N;
   o = Sqrt[n];

   Print["For a=", a, " and b=", b, " and f(x)=", f[x], ",  the mean is ", m, ", k is ", k, ", standard deviation is ", o, ", and variance is ", n, "."] ;

   (* If's don't seem to be a problem *)
   Plot[f[x], {x, If[a == Infinity, 1000, a], If[b == Infinity, 1000, b]},
    (* replaced calls to f with rule replacement; f[x] does not evaluate to what one would expect *)
    Epilog -> {
      Line[{{m, 0}, {m, f[x] /. x -> m}}],
      Line[{{m - o, 0}, {m - o, f[x] /. x -> m - o}}],
      Line[{{m + o, 0}, {m + o, f[x] /. x -> m + o}}]
      }
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

Evaluating

```
(* need to clear k every time otherwise Solve complains *)
Clear[k]
probabilityplot[0, 4, k*x^2]
```

produces

> For a=0 and b=4 and f(x)=0.046875 x^2,  the mean is 3., k is 0.046875, standard deviation is 0.774597, and variance is 0.6.
>   [image]

---

### how I'd have done it

```
(* performs integration*)
integrate[f_, arg_, argMin_, argMax_] := 
  integrate[f, arg, argMin, argMax] = Integrate[f, {arg, argMin, argMax}]

(* solves for *the* parameter - it can handle a single parameter *)
solve[f_, param_, arg_, argMin_, argMax_] := 
  solve[f, param, arg, argMin, argMax] = 
    Solve[1. == integrate[f, arg, argMin, argMax] && param > 0, param]

(* output plot *)
probabilityPlot[f_, param_, arg_, argMin_, argMax_] := 
  Module[{paramSol, paramVal, fVal, mean, var, stdev, text, vals, lowerBound, upperBound, lines},

    paramSol = solve[f, param, arg, argMin, argMax][[-1]];
    paramVal = param /. paramSol;
    fVal = f /. paramSol;

    mean = integrate[fVal arg, arg, argMin, argMax];
    var = integrate[fVal (arg - mean)^2, arg, argMin, argMax];
    stdev = Sqrt[var];

    {lowerBound, upperBound} = Which[# == Infinity, 1000, True, #] & /@ {argMin, argMax};

    text = {"For a=", " and b=", " and f(x)=", ",  the mean is ", ", k is ", ", standard deviation is ", ", and variance is ", "."};
    vals = {argMin, argMax, f, mean, paramVal, stdev, var};

    lines = Line[{{arg, 0.}, {arg, fVal}}] /. {
       {arg -> mean},
       {arg -> mean - stdev},
       {arg -> mean + stdev}
     };

    Print[Row[Riffle[text, vals]]];

    Plot[
     fVal,
     {arg, lowerBound, upperBound},
     Epilog -> lines
    ]

 ]
```

Evaluating

```
probabilityPlot[k s^2, k, s, 0, 4]
```

produces

> For a=0 and b=4 and f(x)=k s^2,  the mean is 3., k is 0.046875,
>   standard deviation is 0.774597, and variance is 0.6.
>   [image]

Comment: Much appreciated. Its my first time using Module and I think I will be using it a lot, and I now have something to refer to. It's much easier to learn if  you understand what is being achieved in a code. I'll also try to incorporate your style of doing the process.

Comment: Much appreciated. Its my first time using Module and I think I will be using it a lot, and I now have something to refer to. It's much easier to learn if  you understand what is being achieved in a code. I'll also try to incorporate your style of doing the process.