# Tag Protected Question

Tags: warning-messages

What I want to do is take a variable `SigmaC` and access it like a set and an array. Ideally, `SigmaC[s]` would give `4` and `SigmaC[[4]]` would give `s`.

This is the code I have tried so far, but it is giving a `Set::write: Tag List ... is Protected` error. How can I fix it?

```
Clear[x, f, u, s, c, b];
SigmaD = SigmaC = {u, f, c, s, b};
PiD = PiC = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
SigmaD[x_] = Position[SigmaD, x];
PiD[x_] = Position[PiD, x];
RelD = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
SigmaC[y_] = Position[SigmaC, y];
PiC[y_] = Position[PiC, y];
RelC = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
```

I haven't been able to find any specific advice on it.

Edit: Actually, none of the function definitions work. 
Extra Edit: Is there a way to overload symbols in Mathematica?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this code? I can't understand it.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is take a variable SigmaC and access it like a set and an array. So SigmaC[s] would give 4 and Sigma[[4]] would give s.

Comment: In your current code, `SigmaD` already has a value when you write `SigmaD[x_] = Position[SigmaD, x];`, so that is interpreted to `{u, f, c, s, b}[x_] = Position[{u, f, c, s, b}, x];`. That does not make much sense, and fails. Similarly with the other definitions.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way around that?

Comment: `PiD` evals to a `List` because it was defined using `Set`. Avoiding that requires usage of `SetDelayed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an underlying association, and interrogate it through a function whose behavior depends on the input "type":

```
assoc = AssociationThread[# -> Range[Length[#]]] &@{u, f, c, s, b};

ClearAll[a]
a[x_Symbol] := assoc[x]
a[n_Integer] := Keys[assoc][[n]]
```

Then you can try:

```
a[c]    (* Out:  3 *)
a[3]    (* Out:  c *)
```

---

If your lists contain duplicates, then `assoc = PositionIndex[yourList]` would be a safer choice to associate symbols with their positions. However, positions are encoded as lists of values in that case, and it is unclear to me what you might want your function to return then.

Answer (score 4):

This answer only addresses how to figure out what caused your error message. Here is what happens when your code is evaluated:

```
Clear[x,f,u,s,c,b];
SigmaD=SigmaC={u,f,c,s,b};
PiD=PiC={1,2,3,4,5,6};
SigmaD[x_]=Position[SigmaD,x];
PiD[x_]=Position[PiD,x];
RelD={{0,1,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0}};
SigmaC[y_]=Position[SigmaC,y];
PiC[y_]=Position[PiC,y];
RelC={{0,0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0}};
```

> Set::write: Tag List in {u,f,c,s,b}[x_] is Protected.
>
> Set::write: Tag List in {1,2,3,4,5,6}[x_] is Protected.
>
> Set::write: Tag List in {u,f,c,s,b}[y_] is Protected.
>
> Set::write: Tag List in {1,2,3,4,5,6}[y_] is Protected.

If you click on the "..." next to the error message, and then select "Show Stack Trace" you will see the following (I clicked on the first message):

> Message[Set::write,List,{u,f,c,s,b}[x_]]
>
> SigmaD[x_]={}
>
> SigmaD[x_]=Position[SigmaD,x];

The entries are displayed in reverse order, with the Message shown first. Here is a recap:

1. Mathematica evaluated the RHS of `SigmaD[x_] = Position[SigmaD, x];` and discovered that `x` was not a member of the list `{u,f,c,s,b}`.  So, the `Position` call evaluated to an empty list `{}`.
2. Now, Mathematica tries to evaluate `SigmaD[x_] = {}`. Of course, `SigmaD` equals `{u,f,c,s,b}` and so a message is generated
3. The message says that `SigmaD[x_]` evaluated to `{u, f, c, s, b}[x_]` but this is not valid syntax for the LHS of a Set statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the code to work, don't use the name of a list as a name of a new function. I have changed the names of the position finding functions by suffixing them with a P. Also use `SetDelayed` for function definition here.

```
Clear[x, f, u, s, c, b];
SigmaD = SigmaC = {u, f, c, s, b};
PiD = PiC = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
SigmaDP[x_] := Position[SigmaD, x];
PiDP[x_] := Position[PiD, x];
RelD = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
SigmaCP[y_] := Position[SigmaC, y];
PiCP[y_] := Position[PiC, y];
RelC = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
```