# System of equations produces error message and no solution

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a set of 9 equations. I keep getting an error letting me know that tag plus in a variable is protected. please help.

```
solve[
  {λ[1]*a* 2*x[1] - 2*λ[3]*x[1] + 2*λ[3]*x[2] == 0, 
   λ[1]*a*2* y[1] - 2*λ[3]*y[1] + 2*λ[3]*y[2] == 0, 
   -m*g - λ[1] - 2*λ[3]*z[1] + 2*λ[3]*z[2] == 0, 
   λ[2]*a*2*x[2] - 2*λ[3]*x[2] + 2*λ[3]*x[1] == 0, 
   λ[2]*a*y[2] - 2*λ[3]*y[2] + 2*λ[3]*y[1] == 0, 
   -m*g - λ[2] - 2*λ[3]*z[2] + 2*λ[3]*z[1] == 0, 
   a^2*x[1]^2 + a^2*y[1]^2 == z[2], a^2*x[2]^2 + a^2*y[2]^2 = z[2], 
   x[1]^2 - 2*x[1]*x[2] + x[2]^2 + y[1]^2 - 2*y[1]*y[2] + y[2]^2 + z[1]^2 - 
      2*z[1]*z[2] + z[2]^2 == L^2}, 
  {x[2], x[2], y[1], y[2], z[1], z[2], λ[1], λ[2], λ[3]}]
```

Tried a bunch of changes and i am still getting the same error message. please advise

Comment: `a^2*x[2]^2 + a^2*y[2]^2 = z[2]` should use `==`, not `=`. `Protected` errors are almost always a rogue `=` somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Comment: You have two x[2] one of them should be x[1] as a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I identify the source of a "Tag times protected" error?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error)

Answer (score 2):

When I rewrite your code — correcting two syntax errors — as:

```
Solve[
  {λ[1]*a* 2*x[1] - 2*λ[3]*x[1] + 2*λ[3]*x[2] == 0, 
   λ[1]*a*2* y[1] - 2*λ[3]*y[1] + 2*λ[3]*y[2] == 0, 
   -m*g - λ[1] - 2*λ[3]*z[1] + 2*λ[3]*z[2] == 0, 
   λ[2]*a*2*x[2] - 2*λ[3]*x[2] + 2*λ[3]*x[1] == 0, 
   λ[2]*a*y[2] - 2*λ[3]*y[2] + 2*λ[3]*y[1] == 0, 
   -m*g - λ[2] - 2*λ[3]*z[2] + 2*λ[3]*z[1] == 0, 
   a^2*x[1]^2 + a^2*y[1]^2 == z[2], a^2*x[2]^2 + a^2*y[2]^2 == z[2], 
   x[1]^2 - 2*x[1]*x[2] + x[2]^2 + y[1]^2 - 2*y[1]*y[2] + y[2]^2 + z[1]^2 - 
      2*z[1]*z[2] + z[2]^2 == L^2}, 
  {x[2], x[2], y[1], y[2], z[1], z[2], λ[1], λ[2], λ[3]}]
```

I get

> `{}`

which is Mathematica's way of saying there is no solution.

#### Note

The two corrections I made are:

1. `Solve` in place of `solve`
2. `a^2*x[1]^2 + a^2*y[1]^2 == z[2], a^2*x[2]^2 + a^2*y[2]^2 == z[2]` in place of `a^2*x[1]^2 + a^2*y[1]^2 == z[2], a^2*x[2]^2 + a^2*y[2]^2 = z[2]`

Comment: Adding option `MaxExtraConditions -> All` to `Solve` gives another solutions ?.