# Tag Times in Null is Protected

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, list-manipulation, assignment

I've some problems with the error mentioned in the title. Unfortunately, my code is full of subscripts so I'll show it in a photo. In this code the central aspect is to assign a scalar value to an element of tensor. The indices of this element of the tensor are given by a certrain array evaluated by some stuff of the code.

When I try to change something I receive the same error

> Tag Times in Null (...) is Protected

The code is given below. After the code there is the photo. Sorry but my laptop has problems with screenshots.

```
Clear[ListaIndici];
CCC = D*Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[x, 7] + 
   K*Subscript[x, 3]*Subscript[x, 4]*Subscript[x, 5] + 
   S*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[x, 6]*Subscript[x, 7];
DimCCC = 3;
Array[TensorCCC, Table[10, DimCCC], 0]; 
ListaCCC = MonomialList[CCC];
Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0];
For[t = 1, t <= Length[ListaCCC], t++,
 For[q = 0, q <= 9, q++,
    If[(D[ListaCCC[[t]], Subscript[x, q]]*
         Subscript[x, q] /ListaCCC[[t]]) == 1, ListaIndici[q] = 1, 
      ListaIndici[q] = 0];
    ]
   TensorCCC @@ Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1] = 
  ListaCCC[[t]]/
   Product[Subscript[x, 
    k - 1], {k, Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1]}] 
(*  there is the error even if we put only 
    TensorCCC @@ Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1] = ListaCCC[[t]] *)]
```

---

[image: code-photo]

How could I solve this problem?

---

#### Edit

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Format[x[n]] := Subscript[x, n];

Clear[ListaIndici]; 
CCC = H*x[1]*x[2]*x[7] + K*x[3]*x[4]*x[5] + S*x[2]*x[6]*x[7]; 
DimCCC = 3; 
Array[TensorCCC, Table[10, DimCCC], 0]; 
ListaCCC = MonomialList[CCC]; 
Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0]; 
Do[Do[If[D[ListaCCC[[t]], x[q]]*(x[q]/ListaCCC[[t]]) == 1, ListaIndici[q] = 1, 
      ListaIndici[q] = 0], {q, 0, 9, 1}]TensorCCC @@ Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 
      1] = ListaCCC[[t]]/Product[x[k - 1], {k, Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1]}], 
  {t, 1, Length[ListaCCC], 1}]
```

Unfortunately the errors remain the same.

Anyway as I said in the comment, I think the problem is also related to the assignment to the tensor through a vector in the way `TensorCCC @@ Position[Array[...]]` is using `@@`.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after the second `For`. Btw.: Try to avoid `Subscript`; it's evil. And better use `Do` instead of `For`. And `D` is a built-in symbol. Don't use it as variable.

Comment: Use indexed variables ([`Making Definitions for Indexed Objects`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)) rather than subscripts. You can **display** the indexed variables as subscripted variables using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html), e.g., `Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]; Array[x, 5]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher OK thank you, there is the photo if you want see clearly the code.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for the info. Please could you tell me something to correct this error.

Comment: Make the recommended changes to your code and if you still have problems, update your question with the revised code showing any errors that are returned. Use the menu command `Cell | Convert To | Raw InputForm` before copy and paste of code.

Comment: @BobHanlon i've edited the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Comment: Hi @MichaelE2 i've put the expression in findBadSets[] it gives this `findBadSets[{K x[3] x[4] x[5], H x[1] x[2] x[7], S x[2] x[6] x[7]}[[
  t]]/(x[{2}] x[{6}] x[{7}])]` , with the error " Part::pkspec1: The expression t cannot be used as a part specification."  Maybe my Mathematica knowledge doesnt find  in this output something useful to problem.

Comment: `Array[TensorCCC, Table[10, DimCCC], 0]` does not create `TensorCCC`.  Check the usage of `Array`.  Also, the inner `Do` loop should be followed by `;`, not `*`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey the * you have seen was caused to the newline of the code converted in raw form. So how could i create an array whose nomber of indices is not known? the vector Table[10,DimCCC] gives a vector of DimCCC (which is given in input ) elements. So i use it to define the number of elements of TensorCCC.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the code shown?  With that information I may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, I believe, produces the desired result:

```
CCC = H*x[1]*x[2]*x[7] + K*x[3]*x[4]*x[5] + S*x[2]*x[6]*x[7];
ListaCCC = MonomialList[CCC];
Do[Do[If[D[ListaCCC[[t]], x[q]]*(x[q]/ListaCCC[[t]]) == 1, 
    ListaIndici[q] = 1, ListaIndici[q] = 0], {q, 0, 9}]; 
    Evaluate[TensorCCC @@ Flatten[Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1]]] = 
    ListaCCC[[t]]/Product[x[k - 1], {k, Flatten[Position[Array[ListaIndici, 10, 0], 1]]}], 
    {t, 1, Length[ListaCCC]}]
```

The key changes from the question are

1. Place a semicolon after the inner `Do`-loop.
2. `Flatten` the result of `Position` to eliminate extraneous curly brackets.
3. `Evaluate` the lhs of the final `Set` to avoid the error messages reported in the question.

In addition, unnecessary lines of code were removed.  To see the result of this computation, use

```
 ?TensorCCC
```

> > Global`TensorCCC
> >
> > TensorCCC[2,3,8]=H
> >
> > TensorCCC[3,7,8]=S
> >
> > TensorCCC[4,5,6]=K

`DownValues` also can be used to show the results.

**Addendum**

A more compact code producing the same results is

```
CCC = H*x[1]*x[2]*x[7] + K*x[3]*x[4]*x[5] + S*x[2]*x[6]*x[7];
(Evaluate[TensorCCC @@ Cases[#, x[z_] -> z + 1]] = First[#]) & /@ CCC;
```

Note that this relies on `{H, K, S}` preceding `x` in canonical order.  If this is not the case, replace `First[#]` by `First@Cases[#, Except[x[_]]]`.

Comment: yes thank you very very much. I've just discovered another expression: at the assignment use `TensorCCC[Sequence @@Position... ]` , unfortunately in this way it doesn't simplify the output giving this  `(H x[1] x[2] x[7])/(x[{1}] x[{2}] x[{7}]) `. Thank you again.

Comment: @siderius  That is because `x[1]` and `x[{1}]` are different variables in Mathematica.  Thanks for accepting my answer.