# Evaluating the 1st argument of Set

Tags: symbolic, list-manipulation, tensors, assignment

I want to assign a certain value to an element of a tensor. This element is identified by an array obtained from some evaluations, so we fix it. Here i present an oversimplified core part of my code:

```
DimensionA = 3;
v = {1, 2, 3};
Array[TensorA, Table[10, DimensionA], 0];  
TensorA @@ v = 12;
```

at this point i receive an error

> Set::write: Tag Apply in TensorA@@{1,2,3} is Protected.

Obviously if i do `TensorA[1, 2, 3] = 12;` it is all ok, but my aim is to give in input a vector with an arbitrary number of indices. Please show me how I should input the vector to the tensor without receiving this error.

Comment: Note that half the code in this question is extraneous.  `v = {1, 2, 3};
Evaluate[TensorA @@ v] = 12` is sufficient to set `TensorA[1, 2, 3]` to `12`.

Comment: Thank you, here there is good related answer right here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183259/tag-times-in-null-is-protected/183324#183324

Comment: I wrote it but did not post a similar answer here, because it would have been the same as the one by @ThatGravityGuy.  Thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 1):

Just force the `Apply` before `Set`.

```
Evaluate[TensorA @@ v] = 12
```

Also for the dimensions specification `Table[10, DimensionA]`, I suggest using `ConstantArray[10, DimensionA]` instead.