# Error while using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm trying to integrate an expression I have for a PDF

$$p(L, \eta)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \mu \tanh (\mu \pi) P_{-1 / 2+i \mu}(\eta) \exp \left[-\left(\mu^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right) \frac{L}{L_{\mathrm{loc}}}\right] d \mu,$$

where

$$P_{-1 / 2+i \mu}(\eta)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \cosh (\pi \mu) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\mu \tau)}{\sqrt{\cosh \tau+\eta}} d \tau.$$

I want to plot the first expression with varying eta. I tried nesting the integrals by writing

```
(*Set constants*)
L = 1
LLoc = 0.4
(*First integral*)

int1[eta_?NumericQ] := 
  (Sqrt[2]/Pi)*Cosh[Pi*mu]NIntegrate[Cos[mu*tau]/Sqrt[(Cosh[tau] + eta)], 
  {tau, 0, Infinity}]

(*Second integral*)
int2[eta_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
  mu*Tanh[mu*Pi]int1[eta]*Exp[-(mu^2 + .25)*(L/LLoc)], {mu, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get a message saying

> `SetDelayed::write` error in `int` ... tag is protected ...

I don't know if I should have `mu` in the argument for integral 1, since it appears in integral 2. Please help.

Comment: First `mu` is undefined. Second missing underscore in the definition `int1[eta_] :=...` and `int2[eta_] :=...`

Comment: I have updated my question...but still some errors and questions. Please help.

Comment: Intead of `Tan` you need `Tanh`. Similarly `Cosh`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Comment: Try `ClearAll[int1, int2]` before defining the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple errors in the posted code.

Here is better code:

```
(*Set constants*)
L = 1;
LLoc = 0.4;

(*First integral*)
Clear[int1];
int1[eta_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NIntegrate[Cos[mu*tau]/Sqrt[(Cosh[tau] + eta)], {tau, 0, Infinity}, opts];

(*Second integral*)
Clear[int2];
int2[eta_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NIntegrate[
   mu*Tanh[mu*Pi]*(Sqrt[2]/Pi)*Cosh[Pi*mu]*int1[eta, mu, opts]*
    Exp[-(mu^2 + .25)*(L/LLoc)], {mu, 0, Infinity}, opts];
```

Together with fixing the errors, I implemented options passing.

Here are examples with the new signature of `int2`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[int2[232]]

(* {2.06321, 0.000370623} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 int2[232, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False, "SingularityHandler" -> None}]
]

(* {0.339009, 0.000370623} *)
```

### Answer to the comment

To compute

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{2}{1+\eta} p(L,\eta) d\eta $$

You will be better off using the approach in [Ulrich Neumann's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210772/34008).

```
NIntegrate[
 2/(1 + eta) * mu *
  Tanh[mu*Pi] ((Sqrt[2]/Pi)*
    Cosh[Pi*mu] Cos[mu*tau]/
     Sqrt[(Cosh[tau] + eta)]) Exp[-(mu^2 + .25)*(L/LLoc)], {tau, 0, 
  Infinity}, {mu, 0, Infinity}, {eta, 1, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
   "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 4]

During evaluation of In[251]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

(* 0.206772 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. SO helpful. If I then want to use int2, inside $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{2}{1+\eta}\bigg)p(L,\eta)d\eta$$ how would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Without error messages MMA evaluates the integrals in one step

```
int[eta_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[mu*Tanh[mu*Pi] ((Sqrt[2]/Pi)*Cosh[Pi*mu] Cos[mu*tau]/Sqrt[(Cosh[tau] + eta)]) Exp[-(mu^2 + .25)*(L/LLoc)], {tau, 0,Infinity}, {mu, 0, Infinity}]

int[232]
(*0.000370623*)
```

Comment: Your post made me aware of not using `mu` "all the way" in my code. Also, I was thinking that the nested integrals should be moved into a proper 2D integral. (+1)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks