# Lengthy NIntegrate with cosine

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm integrating a PDF using

```
Lloc=1
ETau1[L_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2/(1 + eta)*mu*
   Tanh[mu*Pi] ((Sqrt[2]/Pi)*
     Cosh[Pi*mu] Cos[mu*tau]/
      Sqrt[(Cosh[tau] + eta)]) Exp[-(mu^2 + .25)*(L/LLoc)], {tau, 0, 
   Infinity}, {mu, 0, Infinity}, {eta, 1, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
    "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
```

then I want to plot this with varying L using

```
Plot[ETau1[L], {L, 2, 3}]
```

but I get the error that this is a highly oscillatory integral. I'm guessing it's due to the cos(mu*tau) term. How can I fix this?

Comment: The function definition `ETau1[L_?NumericQ] :=` needs an "underscore", `Lloc` isn't defined!

Comment: I define it previously, my mistake. I will amend.

Comment: It solves much faster when I make Lloc small.

Comment: Related to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210769/34008 . (Or spawned from...)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!