# What does tag plus protected mean in this case?

Tags: code-request

I am trying to define a function for future NDSolve use

`oweqn = (1/(c)^2) D[y[t, x], {t, 2}] - D[y[t, x], {x, 2}] + k1 y[t, x] = 0`

Where I predefined $c$ to be a given function of $x$. Everything works perfectly until I entered the above code with which mathematica returned:

Set::write: Tag Plus in y[t,x]-(y^(0,2))[t,x]+(1+2 Sech[x]^2) (y^(2,0))[t,x] is Protected.

I could not see which character in my code is in conflict with predefined mathematica character.

Comment: try changing the end `= 0` to `==0` and see if fixes it.

Comment: Use `FullForm` to see what your expression really looks like. In fact, you do the assignment `Plus[...]=0` instead of building an equation `Plus[...]==0`. Clearly, one cannot assign a zero to the `Plus` tag.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slight modification of [Mr. Wizard's `findBadSets`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11984/4999) that highlights the protected tag with `Inactive` and the erroneous `Set` in red:

```
ClearAll[findBadSets];
SetAttributes[findBadSets, HoldFirst]

findBadSets[expr_] := 
 Cases[Unevaluated@
    expr, (h : Set | SetDelayed)[bad : head_Symbol[___], val_] /; 
     MemberQ[Attributes@head, Protected] :> 
    With[{set = Style[HoldForm@h["", ""], Red],
      badh = Map[InputForm, Inactive[head] @@@ HoldForm@bad, {2}]},
     HoldForm[Row[{head, Spacer[50], badh, set, InputForm@val}]]
     ], -1] // Column

findBadSets[
 oweqn = (1/(c)^2) D[y[t, x], {t, 2}] - D[y[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
    k1 y[t, x] = 0
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]