# Tag plus in ....... is protected. Error

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Code is below, i don't know what to do against these errors because im new to this language,i would appreciate any help :)

### Error

Out[139]= -(0.0000157914/(0.00025 + x[t])^2)

During evaluation of In[127]:= Set::write: Tag Plus in 0.8 i[t]+(L0 (i^[Prime])[t])/(0.005 q w+x[t])-(L0 i[t] (x^[Prime])[t])/(0.005 q w+x[t])^2 is Protected.

During evaluation of In[127]:= Set::write: Tag Plus in If[x[t]>0.013,-p2 (x[t]-xp2),0]+If[x[t]<0.002,-p1 (x[t]-xp1),0]-300 (-0.025+x[t])-(0.5 L0 i[t]^2)/(0.005 q w+x[t])^2-40 (x^[Prime])[t]-0.3 (x^[Prime][Prime])[t] is Protected.

During evaluation of In[127]:= NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of V0[t] in the first argument {V0[t],0,0.013,0.,0.,WhenEvent[x[t]<0,{StopIntegration,Endtime=t}]}.

During evaluation of In[127]:= NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of V0[t] in the first argument {V0[t],0,0.013,0.,0.,WhenEvent[x[t]<0,{StopIntegration,Endtime=t}]}.

During evaluation of In[127]:= Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "t,0.,EndTime)".

---

### Code

```
U0 = 4*pi*10^(-7); W = 0.02; d = 0.015; g = 0.001; r = 0.01; Nturns = 200; R = 0.8;
k = 300; M=0.3; E0 = 10; t0 = 0.3; B = 40; x0 = 0.025; EndTime = 0.06;
plastictickness = 0.002;

p1 = 1000000; xp1 = 0.002;
p2 = 1000000; xp2 = d-xp1;

VO[t_]  := E0*UnitStep[t0-t]

Plot[VO[t], {t, 0, EndTime}]
ClearAll[L,x]
L[x_]:=L0*1/(x[t]+(r*q)/2*w)
L[x]
0.0000157914/(0.00025+x[t])
D[L[x],x[t]]
-0.0000157914/((0.00025+x[t])*(0.00025+x[t]))

sol1 = NDSolve[{R*i[t]+L[x]*Dt[i[t],t]+i[t]*D[L[x],x[t]]*Dt[x[t],t]=V0[t],
-M*Dt[x[t],{t,2}]-B*Dt[x[t],t]+If[x[t]>xp2,-p2*(x[t]-xp2),0]+
If[x[t]<xp1,-p1*(x[t]-xp1),0]-k*(x[t]-x0)+0.5*(i[t]*i[t]*D[L[x],x[t]])=0,
x[0]=xp2-0.00000001,x'[0]=0.,i[0]=0.0,
WhenEvent[x[t]<0, {"StopIntegration",Endtime = t}]},{x,i},{t,0,Endtime}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity];


Plot[{i[t] /. sol1}, (t,0., EndTime), AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Current(A)"},
PlotRange -> All]

Plot[{i[t] / sol1} , (t, 0., EndTime), AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)","Distance (m)"}]
```

---

Comment: All over the place in your code you're using a single equals sign to mean an equality constraint, but a single equals sign means assignment. You want a double equals sign `==` for example `x'[0] == 0` and `Endtime == t` and `... Dt[x[t],t]==V0[t],` . You've also got `U0 = 4*pi*....` at the top - but `pi` is a symbol not the constant `Pi` or `π`

Comment: What is `enter code herex`?

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you're using `Dt` - this doesn't mean derivative with respect to $t$ . It's a total derivative. You can just use `D`.

Comment: You have also not provided the value of `q` or `w` or `L0`, and I would recommend converting the `If`'s to `Piecewise`.

Comment: And you've spelled `EndTime` as `Endtime` in some places - they should be `EndTime`.

Comment: Will try those all @flinty, thanks.

Comment: I edited that @Syed

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Answer (score 5):

A `Set::write: Tag Plus in ... is protected.` error indicates that you have placed a formula, not symbol or pattern, on the left hand side of `Set` (`=`). (`SetDelayed` (`:=`) has an equivalent message.)  In general, when I come across this type of error, I execute the code line by line to find where it is. If you do that, you will find it is in `NDSolve`, specifically it is

```
R*i[t]+L[x]*Dt[i[t],t]+i[t]*D[L[x],x[t]]*Dt[x[t],t]=V0[t]
```

As you can see you used `Set` (`=`) here when you should have used `Equal` (`==`).

The second occurrence, I will leave up to you to find.

Comment: I did try what you said but now im getting a different error. (```NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 0.01299999` in the first argument {0.8 i[t]+(L0 (i^\[Prime])[t])/(0.00025 +x[t])-(L0 i[t] (x^\[Prime])[t])/(0.00025 +x[t])^2==V0[t],If[x[t]>0.013,-p2 (x[t]-xp2),0]+If[x[t]<0.002,-p1 (x[t]-xp1),0]-300 (-0.025+x[t])-(0.5 L0 i[t]^2)/(0.00025 +x[t])^2-40 (x^\[Prime])[t]-0.3 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]==0,0.013,0.,0.,WhenEvent[x[t]<0,{StopIntegration,EndTime=t}]}.```

Comment: @nonamechuck the third element in the list passed to `NDSolve` is fully evaluating to a number. Try clearing global: ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``.