Solve a system of linear equations by NDsolve
Clear[variableName]

max=1;
x1=0.001;xAg=0.001; xTio2=0.001;xGo=0.001;b=2;h=2;(a/c)=1;pAg=10500;pTio2=4250;pGo=1800;pwater=997.1;
kAg=429;kTio2=0.9;kGo=5000;kwater=0.613; bAg=1.89*10^-5;bTio2=0.9*10^-5;bGo=28*10^-5;bwater=21*10^-5;
cAg=6.3*10^7;cTio2=2.38*10^6;cGo=6.3*10^7;cwater=5.5*10-6;Prwater=6.2;cpAg=235;cpTio2=686.2;cpGo=717;cpwater=4179;
kf=1;pf=1;bf=1;M=1;b=1;cf=1;

knf=(kAg+2*kf-2*xAg*(kf-kAg))/(kAg+2*kf+xAg*(kf-kAg));
khnf=(kTio2+2*knf-2*xTio2*(knf-kTio2))/(kTio2+2*knf+xTio2*(knf-kTio2));
kthnf=(kGo+2*khnf-2*xGo*(khnf-kGo))/(kGo+2*khnf+xGo*(khnf-kGo));
kthnf/kf=knf*khnf*kthnf;
cnf=((cAg+2*cwater*xAg*(cwater-cAg))*cwater)/(cAg+2*cwater+xAg*(cwater-cAg));
chnf=(cTio2+2*cnf-2*xTio2*(cnf-cTio2))/(cTio2+2*cnf+xTio2*(cnf-cTio2));
cthnf=(cGo+2*chnf-2*xGo*(chnf-cGo))/(cGo+2*chnf+xGo*(chnf-cGo));
cthnf/cf=cnf*chnf*cthnf;
pthnf1=1-(xAg+xTio2+xGo)+xAg*pAg/pf+xTio2*pTio2/pf+xGo*pGo/pf;
pthnf2=1/((1-xAg)*((1-xTio2)((1-xGo)+xGo(pGo/pwater))+xTio2(pTio2/pwater))+xAg(pAg/pwater));
poh11=NDSolve[{pthnf2(1/((1-xAg)^2.5 (1-xTio2)^2.5 (1-xGo)^2.5))(1+1/b)F'''[\[Eta]]+F[\[Eta]] F''[\[Eta]]-F'[\[Eta]]^2+(pthnf1(1-xAg)((1-xTio2)((1-xGo)pf+xGo (pGo*bGo )/bf)+xTio2 (pTio2*bTio2 )/bf)+xAg (pAg*bAg )/bf)h \[Theta][\[Eta]]+(a/c)^2+pthnf2 cthnf/cf M (a/c-F'[\[Eta]])==0,1/Prwater (kthnf/kf/((1-xAg)((1-xTio2)((1-xGo)+xGo (pGo*cpGo)/(pwater*cpwater))+xTio2 (pTio2*cpTio2)/(pwater*cpwater))+xAg (pAg*cpAg)/(pwater*cpwater)))\[Theta]''[\[Eta]]-F'[\[Eta]]\[Theta][\[Eta]]+F[\[Eta]]\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]==0,F[0]==1,F'[0]==1,F'[max]==a,\[Theta][0]==1,\[Theta][max]==0},{F,\[Theta]},{\[Eta],max}];
p2=Plot[{Evaluate[F[\[Eta]]/.poh11]},{\[Eta],0,max},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->Style[Framed["m=0.3"],12,Blue,Background->Lighter[Yellow]],ImageSize->Large,BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Bold",FontSize->18},AxesLabel->{"\[Eta]","F[\[Eta]]"},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]

These are some errors:
"Tag Times in a/c is Protected"
"Tag Times in (28\Subscript[2, water])/100000 is Protected"
Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at [Eta] == 0.`.
0.00010214285714285715` cannot be used as a variable.
"Tag Times in a/c is Protected"
"Tag Times in (28\Subscript[2, water])/100000 is Protected"
Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at [Eta] == 0.`.
0.00010214285714285715` cannot be used as a variable.
What's the solution??

Where did you get this code? You cannot write something like x/y = z in Mathematica. You can only do x = y*z or y = x/z. So you have to change your lines where you have things like kthnf/kf = ...

Tip: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

Too long for a comment.
Scrape and paste this into a newly opened notebook.
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a=1;aOverc=1;(*(a/c)=1;*)(*kthnf/kf=knf*khnf*kthnf;*)(*cthnf/cf=cnf*chnf*cthnf;*)
max=1;x1=0.001;xAg=0.001;xTio2=0.001;xGo=0.001;b=2;h=2;pAg=10500;pTio2=4250;pGo=1800;pwater=997.1;
kAg=429;kTio2=0.9;kGo=5000;kwater=0.613;bAg=1.89*10^-5;bTio2=0.9*10^-5;bGo=28*10^-5;bwater=21*10^-5;
cAg=6.3*10^7;cTio2=2.38*10^6;cGo=6.3*10^7;cwater=5.5*10-6;Prwater=6.2;cpAg=235;cpTio2=686.2;cpGo=717;
cpwater=4179;kf=1;pf=1;bf=1;M=1;b=1;cf=1;
knf=(kAg+2*kf-2*xAg*(kf-kAg))/(kAg+2*kf+xAg*(kf-kAg));
khnf=(kTio2+2*knf-2*xTio2*(knf-kTio2))/(kTio2+2*knf+xTio2*(knf-kTio2));
kthnf=(kGo+2*khnf-2*xGo*(khnf-kGo))/(kGo+2*khnf+xGo*(khnf-kGo));
cnf=((cAg+2*cwater*xAg*(cwater-cAg))*cwater)/(cAg+2*cwater+xAg*(cwater-cAg));
chnf=(cTio2+2*cnf-2*xTio2*(cnf-cTio2))/(cTio2+2*cnf+xTio2*(cnf-cTio2));
cthnf=(cGo+2*chnf-2*xGo*(chnf-cGo))/(cGo+2*chnf+xGo*(chnf-cGo));
pthnf1=1-(xAg+xTio2+xGo)+xAg*pAg/pf+xTio2*pTio2/pf+xGo*pGo/pf;
pthnf2=1/((1-xAg)*((1-xTio2)((1-xGo)+xGo(pGo/pwater))+xTio2(pTio2/pwater))+xAg(pAg/pwater));
poh11=NDSolve[{pthnf2(1/((1-xAg)^2.5(1-xTio2)^2.5(1-xGo)^2.5))(1+1/b)F'''[\[Eta]]+F[\[Eta]]F''[\[Eta]]-
  F'[\[Eta]]^2+(pthnf1(1-xAg)((1-xTio2)((1-xGo)pf+xGo(pGo*bGo)/bf)+xTio2(pTio2*bTio2)/bf)+xAg(pAg*bAg)/
  bf)h \[Theta][\[Eta]]+aOverc^2+pthnf2 cthnf/cf M(aOverc-F'[\[Eta]])==0,1/Prwater(kthnf/kf/((1-xAg)((1-
  xTio2)((1-xGo)+xGo(pGo*cpGo)/(pwater*cpwater))+xTio2(pTio2*cpTio2)/(pwater*cpwater))+xAg(pAg*cpAg)/
  (pwater*cpwater)))\[Theta]''[\[Eta]]-F'[\[Eta]]\[Theta][\[Eta]]+F[\[Eta]]\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]==0,F[0]==1,
  F'[0]==1,F'[max]==a,\[Theta][0]==1,\[Theta][max]==0},{F,\[Theta]},{\[Eta],max}];
Plot[{Evaluate[F[\[Eta]]/.poh11]},{\[Eta],0,max}]

And you should see your plot.
Please check every change very carefully to try to make certain that this does exactly what you want.
