Can I make missing semicolons in Module more obvious in the front end?
I use Module a lot to localize symbols. Occasionally I will forget a semicolon on one of the lines in the middle, and don't notice until I get flooded with Tag Times Protected warnings, because the missing semicolon leads MMA to interpret the two lines as being multiplied. The only visual indicator in the code (at least in .wl files) is the faint \[Times] symbol at the end of the offending line. See if you can spot which line in the screenshot at the end of the post is the problem! (its a lne near the middle, above the blue-highlighted slicesSummarizer.
The question: is there a setting or option in the option inspector, or other tricks, to make this much more visually obvious, particulary in .wl files? (Particularly without waiting until the evaluation vomits warnings on me?)
related
also related
Neither answer addressed whether there's a code-highlighting options or something that can address this. It may not be possible, particularly as I like to spread certain expressions like the definition of Associations over several lines, so a new line is not always needing the semicolon.


https://i.sstatic.net/YjcYRfUx.png :)

@xzczd indeed! the bane of my existence!

You can try Evaluation->Analyze notebook and see if it flags this or not.

Would you be happy with SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, NumberMultiplier -> "❌❌❌"]? :D

If you write the Module so that every statement is on a separate line, you can see missing semicolons by an additional indent and a faint "x" in place of the missing ";".

@Domen um.... actually YES, that is genuinely something I think i'm going to do...

Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/how-do-i-identify-the-source-of-a-tag-times-protected-error

You could put semicolons at the beginning of lines, as some other users do. https://i.sstatic.net/XZ6JQ1cg.png

As you've figured it out yourself, if you don't put a semicolon, the two expressions are interpreted as being multiplied, and there is a gray multiplication symbol in between. This is set by AutoMultiplicationNumber, which by default also includes "LineBreaks" (hard line breaks that imply multiplication).
The symbol in between is set by NumberMultiplier, however, it doesn't seem to allow any styling, only a pure string. So you can resort to using some colorful and bright emojis:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, NumberMultiplier -> "❌ MISSING SEMICOLON "]


Note that if you use function multiplication, like f[x] g[x], you probably want to exclude it from getting the automatic multiplication symbol:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> {"LineBreaks", "Numbers"}]

