# Manipulate Command giving error

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-50, 50}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{a x^2 + b x + c = y}]], {{a, .1}, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, {{b, .1}, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, {{c, .1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

Then I am having this after evaluating:

> ```
> Set::write: Tag Plus in 0.1 +0.1 x+0.1 x^2 is Protected.
> ```

What does this mean?

Comment: You have a [basic syntax error](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/20144) in your `PlotLabel` option.

Comment: To expand slightly on @dionys comment, you will want to enclose the equation you are using as a plot label in quotes to make it a string and prevent *Mathematica* from trying to evaluate it by assigning values to the left hand side.

Comment: Other duplicates: [(11868)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11868), [(11982)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982)

Answer (score 1):

You have assign ([`=`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) instead of [`==`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) in the:

```
{a x^2 + b x + c = y}
```

Just change this into and this will be fixed.

```
{a x^2 + b x + c == y}
```